# Append git's branch name to command prompt

Tags: git, bash, shell

I wanted to use one of the Git-completion.bash features but I can't customize the look I'd like to have. Here is relevant part of my .bash_profile:

```
source ~/.git-completion.bash

function prompt
{
local WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
local GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
export PS1="
${GREEN}\u${CYAN}@${BLUE}\h ${CYAN}\w $(__git_ps1 '(%s)') ${GRAY}
$ "
}
prompt
```

and it doesn't show the branch name.

However, if I replace export PS1 above with the one below, it works as expected:

```
export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '
```

I guess it's some apostrophe / quotation marks issue.

How should I correct the 1st version to get it to work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The trick to get the quoting right is to have eveything double-quoted, except for `$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")`, which is single-quoted.

```
source ~/.git-completion.bash
function prompt
{
local WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
local GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
export PS1="
${GREEN}\u${CYAN}@${BLUE}\h ${CYAN}\w"' $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") '"${GRAY}"
}
prompt
```

An alternative solution is to replace `$(` with `\$(` in the code in the question.

Background information: Two substitutions take place: first at `export PS1="..."` time, and later when the prompt is displayed. You want to execute `__git_ps1` each time the prompt is displayed, so you have to make sure that the first substitution keeps `$(...)` intact. So you write either `'$(...)'` or `"\$(...)"`. These are the two basic ideas behind the solutions I've proposed.

Comment: Using the locals for the colors is a nice trick to make the thing readable. I'm stealing that idea for sure. FYI for others, I kind of like using yellow for my path - `local YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, but [vcprompt](http://vc.gerg.ca/hg/vcprompt/) might solve it better for you?

Comment: It probably doesn't cover all the options of __git_ps1 in git-completion.bash, but I really like the fact that it gives information about other version control systems as well. Thanks for the tip!