# Git history - find lost line by keyword

Tags: git, version-control

I had somewhere in my Git repository a line containing the word "Foo" a couple of hundreds of commits before.

If there is any way to find its revision number where it was the last time?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

That may be addressed by the **pickaxe** (`-S`) option of [`gitlog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

```
 git log -SFoo -- path_containing_change
```

(you can even add a time range: `--since=2009.1.1 --until=2010.1.1`)

```
-S<string>
```

> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of `<string>`.
>   Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in [gitdiffcore(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitdiffcore.html) for more details.

```
diffcore-pickaxe
```

> This transformation is used to find filepairs that represent changes that touch a specified string.
>   When `diffcore-pickaxe` is in use, it checks if there are filepairs whose "original" side has the specified string and whose "result" side does not.
>   Such a filepair represents "the string appeared in this changeset".
>   It also checks for the opposite case that loses the specified string.

---

Update 2014:

Since then, you can do (from [nilbus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87298/nilbus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226807/6309)):

```
git log -p --all -S 'search string'
git log -p --all -G 'match regular expression'
```

> These log commands list commits that add or remove the given search string/regex, (generally) more recent first.
>   The `-p` (`--patch`) option causes the relevant diff to be shown where the pattern was added or removed, so you can see it in context.
>
> Having found a relevant commit that adds the text you were looking for (eg. `8beeff00d`), find the branches that contain the commit:

```
git branch -a --contains 8beeff00d
```

(I reference that last command in "[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)")

Comment: Note to self: the relation between `--pickaxe-all` and `-S` can be better understood with http://lists-archives.org/git/715566-git-log-why-are-full-diff-and-pickaxe-all-separate-options.html and http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/34909

Comment: Quite a shoutout, thanks! Conversely, I always know if you've hit a question there's no need for me to answer.

Comment: @Jefromi: "I always know if you've hit a question there's no need for me to answer.". Well... about that. It never hurt to check ;) I am still learning here. For instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846843/find-the-git-branch-or-branches-from-commit-id/2846918#2846918 might benefit from your expertise.

Comment: Okay, there are exceptions to every rule; I do check, but very rarely am needed!

Answer (score 1):

Worst case scenario, use [`git bisect`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) and `grep`?