# Find the git branch or branches from commit id

Tags: git, commit, sha1, git-branch, blame

Actually am try to get a report on merge conflicts. I used 'git blame' to see who has changed what line, but i couldn't find the branch and repository name information.

Is there a way to find the repository name, branch name and author name of a file from 'git blame' or from commit ids' so that whenever a merge conflict occurs i can send an email to the authors who have touched that file/lines to resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding what branch a git commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`git blame`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) should only give you the revision and author, but:

- as mentioned in "[Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)", you cannot easily pinpoint the branch where that commit has been made (branches can be renamed, moved, deleted...), even though `git branch --contains <commit>` is a start.
- I doubt you can find the repository it came from (unless maybe by looking hard in the `git log` results, trying to find the parent of that commit comming from a `ref/remotes` namespace).

Now if you have a proper `.mailmap` at the toplevel of the repository, you will have the right email addresses as well.

> In the simple form, each line in the file consists of a canonical real name of an author, a whitespace, and an email address used in the commit (enclosed by `<` and `>`) to map to the name. For example:

```
Proper Name <commit@email.xx>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So there is no direct way :(
Can you educate me n how to backtrack a code/file. Git blame will tell the commit and author. Is there a way to backtrack from the commit id?

Comment: @Senthil: I answered the question VonC links to with a few ways you may be able to backtrack.

Comment: Thanks Jefromi got your link too :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from/2707110#2707110)

@VonC thanks a lot, am settling with author name alone for merge conflicts