# OpenCMIS: Example uses a class I can't find in the whole source

Tags: java, cmis

I am trying to run the CMIS client example on:
http://incubator.apache.org/chemistry/opencmis-api-examples.html

Unfortunately I can't find the "SessionParameter" class that the example uses.
It is nowhere to be found in the whole project's source code:
http://github.com/apache/chemistry

What did I miss?
Or maybe the example is out-of-date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples are up-to-date and working. The current and maintained code stream of Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS is here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/

But this code stream is not on github.

Answer (score 2):

`SessionParameter` is no longer part of the *GitHub* project.

A simple `git log -SSessionParameter --oneline` can reveal a lot:
(see "[Git history - find lost line by keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839253/git-history-find-lost-line-by-keyword/2839319#2839319)")

```
/c/HOMEWARE/chemistry (trunk)
$ git log -SSessionParameter --oneline
0c08a4f Retiring old OpenCMIS code stream
02a76c0 CMIS-183 Offer ObjectGenerator also as standalone command line tool Prov
40052d4 repository info cleanup
4a6fccf Refactoring client runtime unit tests - move to FIT module - run with je
f37febd Unit test cases for r/w introduced
7d74230 Client Runtime Junit Test Improvment using InMemory Provider
60e4e1f bug in mock test fixed
52e5bc3 client runtime implementation - unit test re-factoring after API changes
47dbe64 first step to make provider layer thread-safe (CMIS-155)
8519c74 added repository discovery to SessionFactory
7a9946b https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-124
7bbf13f cleaned up context handling improved PagingList disabled caching for now
bb35c83 client runtime implementation - unit test improvement https://issues.apa
13bb41b - activated client API integration tests
dabd12a - allow custom authentication providers in createCmisAtomPubProvider and
d79e8ff Continuous Runtime Implementation and Unit Tests - runtime implementatio
c661109 Continuous runtime development
5d12b63 API SessionParameter clean up and re-factoring https://issues.apache.org
c5d8e04 InMemory impl: let VersioningTest make use of AbstractServieTst
e542e11 Re-factoring package names of JUnit tests
8f16d0f Synchronize latest code changes from BerliOS
84d4762 CMIS-122: OpenCMIS integration test framework
d01e33d InMemoryProvider: bugfix versioning: only checked out documents can be m
9499459 Initial contribution of OpenCMIS (CMIS-113).
```

The firstlog i n particular displays:

```
commit 0c08a4fa7207c0399768e28e0912b626e5ac02d0
Author: Florian M<C3><BC>ller <fmui@apache.org>
Date:   Wed May 5 09:03:22 2010 +0000

    Retiring old OpenCMIS code stream

    git-svn-id: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/chemistry/trunk@94120
```

Meaning that implementation can be found at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/chemistry/trunk.
In particular: [`SessionParameter.java`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/chemistry/old/opencmis/opencmis-commons/opencmis-commons-api/src/main/java/org/apache/opencmis/commons/SessionParameter.java)

[Florian Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345826/florian-muller) himself [confirms it above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871416/opencmis-example-uses-a-class-i-cant-find-in-the-whole-source/2871729#2871729) ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this! The classes I need are actually at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/ and are not considered old but just another part of the project, waiting for ingestion after a recent fusion between the two projects.

Comment: @Nicolas: thank you for this precision (I am not familiar with this project)