# Git: get all blobs with pattern

Tags: git, grep

In Git, how do I find the SHA-1 IDs of all blobs in the object database that contain a string pattern? `git-grep` provides only the file paths and not the sha1 IDs.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Update based on new testing results using Git version 2.7.4

Looks like the solution I posted only goes through the reflog. So if you delete a reflog entry, that entry will not be searched through - even though the object still exists.

So you will have to do something like:

```
{
    git rev-list --objects --all --grep="text"
    git rev-list --objects -g --no-walk --all --grep="text"
    git rev-list --objects --no-walk --grep="text" \
        $(git fsck --unreachable |
          grep '^unreachable commit' |
          cut -d' ' -f3)
} | sort | uniq
```

Derived from: [Git - how to list ALL objects in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348698/git-how-to-list-all-objects-in-the-database)

**Old solution: Only works if object is in reflog**

To find the string "text" in all local objects:

```
git log --reflog -Stext
```

To find the pattern "pattern" in all local objects:

```
git log --reflog --grep=pattern
```

This will search through all objects, so it will work even if the commit/branch is deleted. Once an object is removed from the local repository (e.g. through a gc), it will no longer be included in the search.

Comment: I usually don't need to search through deleted element (don't forget the reflog is local to your repo: if you clone it again, the reflog will be empty). But for a local search in the same repo, that will indeed work. +1

Comment: Right, I agree that is it not common to search through all objects. However, this is what the OP wants. Can be useful, one example I can think of is if you mistakenly committed a password and want to get rid of it from the local repository. Another would be if you deleted something from the reflog and want to recover it (assuming a gc has not removed the blob).

Comment: I have tried but It didn't work (grep just not work this case, document says git-rev-list --grep is for commit message but not blob content, maybe it is the reason?). But I found another solution following the guidance: `git grep 'text' $(git fsck --unreachable | grep '^unreachable blob' | cut -d' ' -f3)` did search all unreachable blobs for the text

Answer (score 4):

I did the following to figure out if some code I'd written was lost forever, or was perhaps hidden in some "unreachable" commit:

```
# Assuming you're at the root of the git repository
> cd .git/objects
# Search all objects for a given string (assuming you're in .git/objects)
> find ?? -type f | sed s!/!! | git cat-file --batch | grep --binary-files=text <SEARCH_STRING>
```

This will produce output  if *any* git object contains `<SEARCH_STRING>`. However, it won't tell you which object contains it. But by doing this, I found my missing code and I was eventually able to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a git log using the pickaxe option:

```
git log -Sstring --all
```

See "[How to find commit SHA1 of a tree containing a file containing a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451232/how-to-find-commit-sha1-of-a-tree-containing-a-file-containing-a-given-string)"

Comment: This only searches through the refs. not all objects like the OP wants. Once a commit/branch is deleted, your search will not work. I posted an answer using a modified version of your solution.