# Git repo size on filesystem is way larger than its clone

Tags: git

I need to deal with a git repository hosted on a gitlab instance. The `repo.git/objects` folder is 3.8GB large on the server's filesystem (it the same same as reported in GitLab's UI).

However when I'm cloning it with `git --mirror remote-url`, it's only 120MB large... !?

I've read http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html and indeed there are remotes branch, but even after following the "deep clone" step and issuing `git fetch --all` I don't see any differences. What's happening here ?

My ultimate goal is then to shrink/cleanup the repo on disk, of course.

Comment: Try `git clone --mirror`. There might be some pull-request-like refs, which are not merged to branches.

Comment: adding `--mirror` has the same exact effect

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348698/git-how-to-list-all-objects-in-the-database. List all objects in both repositories, sort and compare two results.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay but... Then what ?

Comment: Find the difference and what are missing. Objects are the meta data of a git repository. If they are the same, maybe the Gitlab repo needs `git gc`.

Comment: They are clearly not the same : I gathered both objects lists and there are more in the one on the filesystem. Could it be something linked with LFS ?

Comment: I can't see any LFS files with `git lfs ls-files` from a regular clone of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue with `sudo -u git git gc`

GC is ran by GitLab only after a specific number of push cycles

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/housekeeping.html