# Undo git push --delete <branch>

Tags: git

I have done the following:

1. Cloning a repo
2. `git push origin --delete Branch_Name`

and branch is deleted.

Is there any way I can restore this?
I did not checkout this branch before deletion so there is no local copy.

---

git reflog is useless I guess cause I did not checkout the branch
and I also don't know the commit_id of last commit on this branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the only way to recover from this is to find a repository—often one used by a colleague / friend / co-worker—who has the right commit(s), or to use the server's backups (your server *does* have backups made and tested regularly, right? Right?!? ).  The reason for this is:

- Server-side Git repositories have reflogs disabled by default.
- Even if not, deleting the server's branch name with `git push --delete` deletes any relevant reflog the server had.
- It deletes your own remote-tracking branch as well: your `origin/branch` is gone, along with any reflog you had for that.

The branch-name deletion may not have triggered a `git gc` in the server (this is not predictable) and definitely did not trigger one in your own repository (this, fortunately, *is*), so if you know the right *hash ID*, you can run:

```
git push origin <hash>:refs/heads/branch
```

but you usually don't know the right hash ID: that information *was* in the branch name on the server (gone now), your remote-tracking name (gone now), and any relevant reflogs in your and/or the server's repository (all of which are gone now).

That information *does* exist in any colleague's clone, provided that they (a) *have* run `git fetch origin` relatively recently **and** (b) *have not* run `git fetch origin` in such a way that *their* Git *also* deleted the information.  This is the only reason I know of that one might *not* want to set `fetch.prune` to `true`: it causes your own Git repository to retain stale remote-tracking names, in case one of your colleagues executes this particular stunt.

Since responsible server sites make regular backups, though, you can always recover the information from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you did Step 2 not long after Step 1, you can try `git push origin origin/[Branch_Name]:refs/heads/[Branch_Name]` to recreate the branch from the most possible commit.

Comment: yes, I did the exact sequence.. clone then delete.

just tried this command but it says, `error: src refspec branch_name does not match any.`

Comment: @ATEF try `refs/remotes/origin/branch_name:/refs/heads/branch_name` instead.

Comment: @ATEF Suppose the branch is `foo` and try `git push origin origin/foo:refs/heads/foo` or `git push origin refs/remotes/origin/foo:refs/heads/foo`.

Comment: not working guys :(. anyway, thank you I ended up asking if anyone has a local copy and we found one. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other developer who has a local copy of the branch?
If any, ask her/him to push that branch.

Details:

The local repository keeps the latest commit object for that branch, but it's difficult to identify the commit because the information about the commit-branch relationship has been lost by `git push origin --delete [Branch_Name]`. However, if you can find the commit from the list of commit objects, you can checkout and regenerate the branch.

In many cases it's faster to ask other developers to push the branch from their repository, if any.

Comment: ended up doing that yeah but I hoped to find a better solution

Comment: The relation between [Branch_Name] and the latest commit in that branch will be lost by `git push origin --delete [Branch_Name]` from your local repository and the remote repository. On the other hand, the commit object should remain in your local repository, and you can checkout the one and re-create the branch if you can identify it by some commit information.

Comment: To list up objects in your repository, you can use `git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348698/how-to-list-all-git-objects-in-the-database

Comment: Thank you. appreciate your support.

Comment: I learned that `git fsck` can be used for this purpose. You can use it to extract commits that are no longer referenced.