# which commit was cherry-picked?

Tags: git, history, cherry-pick, reflog

How can you find out which commit was used in a cherry-pick operation? git reflog only seems to show the resulting commit Sha-1 after the cherry-pick is merged and commited. We need to find the original commit prior to that.

Why? It's because we mistakenly cherry-picked a large, but incorrect commit to a different branch. But noone realized it until after modifying it so that it compiles plus added other commits after it.

The goal here is to compare this resulting cherry-pick from the original one and use those differences either as a patch or to manually make the same changes to the correct cherry-pick.

Comment: Why can't you just diff the cherry-picked commit with its parent?

Comment: See also: [which commits got cherry-picked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11719926/456814).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922652/git-is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-where-a-commit-was-cherry-picked-from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Is there a way to figure out where a commit was cherry-pick'ed from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922652/git-is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-where-a-commit-was-cherry-picked-from)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the git log -p output. You may be able to do it with --stat as well.