# which commits got cherry-picked

Tags: git, cherry-pick

a basic question probably. I have cherry-picked some commits across branches. Now I would like to get a list of the commits from branch A that got cherry-picked to branch B. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Different commits between two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/different-commits-between-two-branches)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922652/git-is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-where-a-commit-was-cherry-picked-from

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git log --oneline --cherry A...B
```

This lists all commits that are in B but not in A and marks commits that have an equivalent commit in A with `=`