# Is there a way to know if a particular git commit to a branch is in another branch as well?

Tags: git

Is there a way to know if the code change for a particular commit on a branch is in another branch as well (whether it be via git cherry-pick or merge)

I have two branches of code and occasionally some commits that goes into one branch should also go into another.  How do I find out what commit was done to branch A but not B (and vice versa - what's done to both).  Right now I am manually checking the commit changes in both branches.

Comment: `git branch --contains <commit>` lists the branches that contain `<commit>`.

Comment: I think searching for the commit message is the only way forward for `cherry-pick`ed commits. Git treats them as separate commits.

Comment: If you cherry-picked with `-x` the commit messages of the cherry-picked commits will mention the original hash ID. [More details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2937724/354577).

Comment: @Jubobs Can't do git branch --contains because some commits are cherry-picked.

Comment: A particular commit is identified by a unique commit ID. Different commit IDs <=> different commits. You should clarify your question.

Comment: I did clarify by saying it can be done via git cherry-pick.

Comment: you can see commits that are in branch2 but not in branch1 by:
    git rev-list branch1..branch2

Answer (score 1):

The [`git cherry` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html) will usually do the trick, although it's designed for a slightly different purpose and thus may not be as convenient as you might like.

Read the [documentation for `git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) as well.  This should give you some idea of the limitations of this method (in particular if a commit must be modified during cherry-picking, it may look too different afterwards to be found).

Once you have digested both of those (and experimented with them if needed), read the [`git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) and pay attention to the `--cherry-mark` and `--cherry-pick` options.  Using these with the symmetric difference operator (`A...B`) will allow you to automate most of what you want here.