# Is there any way to see which commit is cherry-picked to a commit?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log, cherry-pick, git-show

Assume that there are two branch `develop` and `master`.

They are like this (alphabets are commits), master was created based on `develop` at B:

A — B — C — D (develop)

A — B — E — F — (C cherry-picked) — G — H (master)

How can I confirm `C cherry-picked` is picked from `C` from the upper part?

Fortunately I can recognize commits by commit messages so far. However, I wonder if it is possible to confirm like above.

I know that `commit` is not `difference` but like a snapshot.
and `cherry-pick` is calculated between commits.

In this case, I could compare the results of these below:

```
git diff F (C cherry-picked)
git diff B C
```

or

```
git show C
git show (C cherry—picked)
```

I hope there is a better way..

Comment: Use command git cherry. It finds which commits have been cherry picked.

Comment: This is a very meaty thread on cherry-pick; in fact perhaps too meaty for this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922652/git-is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-where-a-commit-was-cherry-picked-from