# How can I see which branches or tags on Github include a specific commit?

Tags: git, github

I've just hit a bug in a project on Github. I found an issue listed for the bug, and it lists a commit that supposedly fixes the problem.

**How can I see which branches or tags, if any, include the commit that fixed the bug?** I'd like to do this on Github, if possible, but a pure git solution would be OK, too.

Comment: Does this really deserve to be closed? The question asks about how to do this on github, but the question it supposedly duplicates makes no mention of the github UI, and the answer is only suitable if you're in a position to clone the repo. I suspect that's the best that's possible, but I was hoping to be proven wrong.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely not a duplicate. I just arrived with the same question: Can it be done on GitHub? The answer seems to be "No."

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/git-how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit) Charles B posted, which explains how to find the branches, you can use `git tag --contains` as an equivalent command for for finding tags that contain the commit.