# Get the "Pull Request Name" from a file/line

Tags: git, github

Given a file and a specific line, for example `myFile.php line 123`,
will be possible to get information about which pull request or branch or issue
the line of code has been added?

Answer (score 1):

You need `git blame`.
Read [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html)

If you want to do it through UI, then using `git gui` you can browse the files.

Now to answer your question : You will find a SHA1 Commit ID in which each line was modified. You can map it to some branch by searching for it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/git-how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: +1, thanks for your answer. Actually `git branch --contains` display just the branch which contains the modification. Actually I would like to access the first branch or the name of the pull request where this change has been made. Any hints?