# Git: How to find which branches a commit was merged into?

Tags: git

Given a Git commit ID for a set of changes, how do I find which branches this commit was merged into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Answer (score 4):

A commit has been merged into a branch if it's part of that branch history (list of commits). So that should do:

```
 git branch --contains <commit>
```