# How to find the branch of a commit?

Tags: git

When I am in my local repo and do

```
git show <commit-SHA>
```

it shows me the commit and its associated file changes.

But git does a search across all branches in the repo, not just the branch I am currently in.  How do I get it to display in which of the local branches that commit is located?

Comment: Do you want to know which branches can trace their lineage back to include that commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know which branches contain a commit, you can use

```
git branch --contains COMMIT_ID
```

This will show you all branches that an trace their history back to the given commit.

As an aside, git doesn't do a "search across all branches" to find a commit for `git show`; The point of the SHA1 sum is that Git can go immediately to the object in question because its content can never change.