# Understanding Git Branches graph view

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Can anyone kindly explain me what is going on here >

[image]

git log shows me that 'edit cm.api.post' is the HEAD of Broadcast-feature branch. However the graph shows there are other commits on the same branch as well.

Note: This graph is of our 'master' branch (left-most line is master). When I view graph of 'Broadcast-feature' only then it shows fine with no extra commits

Comment: Try this [git branch --contains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/654369) to find branches that contain latest commit from `Broadcat-feature` branch. `git branch --contains Broadcast-feature`. It seems like you have another branch based on `Broadcast-feature` branch.

Comment: How did you create that graph shown in the screenshot?

Comment: @michas, as for me it looks similar to SourceTree.

Answer (score 5):

For those coming from Google looking how to fix the commit order for the git-flow: choose "Date Order" instead of "Ancestor Order":

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just scroll up your graph a little bit further to see in what branch those commits end up.

Someone created another branch starting at "broadcast-feature". The commits shown are the commits contained in that branch.

Remember: In git a "branch" is not much more than a label for some commit.

Comment: when a new branch is created, shouldn't a new color line branch off from there ?

Comment: No, actually there is no "real" branch in git. They are really just labels for commits. The "branch" your are thinking of, is only implicitly given by the ancestors of that commit. Those lines only indicate that one commit is the parent of the other. The colors are drawn by sourcetree to make it easier to follow long lines.