# List of branches a commit appears on

Tags: github, github-api

Using the GitHub API (v3) I'd like to figure out which branches a commit appears on. I didn't find a way to directly query this, either through repo commits or the commit data objects. An alternate solution would be to list all the branches, and compare with their HEAD; I guess the comparison would fail if the commit is not on the given branch.

Is this supported via the current API, and I just missed it? If not, do you have a (better) workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: @Cupcake Unfortunately I need to do this using the GitHub API, if at all possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's not possible directly via the GitHub API.

#### Workaround 1:

1. get a [list of all branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-branches)
2. for each branch, get a [list of commits on that branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository)
3. check if the commit is in the list of commits for each branch

#### Workaround 2 (I *think* this will work, but not 100% sure if I missed a case):

1. get a [list of all branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-branches)
2. for each branch, [compare the branch with the SHA](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits):

   `https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/compare/:branch...:sha_of_commit`
3. If the value of the `status` attribute in the response is `diverged` or `ahead`, then the commit is not in the branch. If the value of the `status` attribute is `behind` or `identical`, then the commit is in the branch.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked if this is directly supported by the GitHub API, but this is trivial to do using plain Git:

```
git branch --all --contains <commit>
```

That will list all branches (local and remote) in a local repository that contain the given commit.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this using the GitHub API, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct endpoint to list the branches by a commit ID. But you can use a combination of other endpoints to solve this.

**Condition 1**
Use [branches-where-head endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#list-branches-for-head-commit) to get the name of the branches where the given commit ID is the head.

**Condition 2**
If condition 1 returns empty, get pull info object using the commit ID and extract the branch information using [pulls info endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit).
***Tip:*** The return object contains properties - base.ref and head.ref which has the branch name. If base.ref is the name of the master branch, use head.ref which should give you the name of the branches that contains the commit ID.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone using the PyGitHub (https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) library for API calls -

First get the list of all branches and then

```
g = Github(<accesskey>)
repo = g.get_repo(<repository>)
is_commit_in_branch = repo.compare('stable-2.11', <commit_id>).status
# If it returns behind or identical, then the commit is in the branch.
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Git*Lab* API

Following [Ivan Zuzak's solution number 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23970412/119527), to know if a *commit* is on a *branch*:

Use GitLab's [repository compare](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits) API, and compare *from* the branch, *to* the commit

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/compare?from=<branch>&to=<sha_of_commit>
```

If the `commits` list is empty, then yes, the commit is on that branch.

In Python, using [python-gitlab](http://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io):

```python
def is_commit_on_branch(project, commit, branch):
    c = project.repository_compare(branch, commit)
    return not c['commits']
```