# Github API: Check if a branch or repository contains a commit

Tags: github, github-api

Can I use the Github API to check if a certain repository contains a certain commit?

At first glance, it seems that [the get a single commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit) API call should work, returning 404 if there is no such commit in the repository. But that is not true: It seems that this call will run successful on commits that are present in forked repositories (possibly due to a pull request). (This effect can also be observed in the [regular web interface](https://github.com/dspinellis/fileprune/commit/782da80c5862eb0845e8d65fe3e18e34862b512a); this particular commit has not been pulled into that repository yet.)

Comment: Of course, I'm guessing cloning the repository locally for inspection is out of the question... Right?

Comment: Of course that's the alternative, but wouldn't qualify as an answer to this question about the GitHub API.

Comment: Maybe you can use approach 2 from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899329/list-of-branches-a-commit-appears-on/23970412#23970412

Comment: That’s a useful hint!

Answer (score 4):

#### Api GitHub search

For searching other repositories one can use the api, which finds commits via various criteria. (This method returns up to 100 results per page.):

- https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits
- Only the default branch is considered, mostly master

#### Api usage

- GET /search/commits
- **q** can be any kind of search term combination: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-commits/

#### Example parameters for q

- `hash:124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105`
  Matches commits with the hash `124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105`.
- `parent:124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105`
  Matches children of `124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105`.

further parameters, like sorting, ordering can be found in the documentation above.

#### Usage example per hash:

- **example call** `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=<searchterm>+<searchterm2>`
- **specific call**: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:adejoux/kitchen-wpar+hash:0a3a228e5b250daf06f933b35b3f0eafc715be4f`

You need to add an special header, because the api is available for developers to preview

**header to add:** application/vnd.github.cloak-preview