# GitHub REST API: git tag --contains

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to identify all the tags that contains a specific commit. Using git command tools, this can be done through:

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

However, I need to do this for several repositories so I was expecting on relying on the REST API. Is there a way to gather the same information through GitHub's REST API?

Answer (score 3):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899329/list-of-branches-a-commit-appears-on/23970412#23970412) on a related question to give me what I needed.

You would first [get a list of tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) for your repo:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/tags
```

Then, for each tag, you would [compare the branch with the SHA](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/compare/:tagName...:sha_of_commit
```

If the value of the `status` attribute in the response is `diverged` or `ahead`, then the commit is not contained in the tag. If the value of the `status` attribute is `behind` or `identical`, then the commit is contained in the tag.