# List all tags containing a commit or PR on github

Tags: github, github-api

How can I determine if a given tag in a repository on github (to which I have access) includes a particular commit or pull request. Essentially, which tagged versions include a particular fix/extension that the commit or PR represent.

My question is essentially similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit), except I would like to do it either on a remote clone (eg: github) or via the github web interface.

Comment: I think the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184945/github-rest-api-git-tag-contains) might help
.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126420/420867) can do what I'm after, but it's rather involved. I was hoping for a simpler solution, but it seems it likely doesn't exist.