# How do I find out which remote git branch I checked out?

Tags: git

```
git checkout origin/some_remote_branch
...
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state....
```

How do I later find out what I checked out?

Comment: Is there a use case for this or did you just mistakenly type "origin/" and need a one time recovery?

Comment: This is for a specific usecase. I checked out a tag we released to a customer. I might make some changes to it; I might make a branch out of it later, I'm not sure... I just want to be able to tell where I am :)

Comment: Newer versions of git do a much better job in `git status` output.  For the tag case specifically you can always do `git describe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple command: [`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

In the case of a detached head, you'll get this message:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at origin/master
```

Comment: This looks good, except I don't get the same message. The message I get looks like: # Not currently on any branch. Maybe I'm on an old git version? 1.7.12.4 and 1.8.2 give the same (checked out using 1.7.12.4)

Answer (score 0):

try: `git status`

It should tell you what branch you're on and the state of any changes you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather create a local branch based on the remote branch you want to check out.
*Then*, a `git status` would be more helpful (instead of the current "`Not currently on any branch`")

```
git checkout -b some_remote_branch origin/some_remote_branch
```

Otherwise, all you could do is list the branches which includes the commit you are currently at (in a [detached HEAD situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)):

```
git branch -r --contains <commit>
```

(as in "[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419623/6309)")