# How to find out which remote branch remote HEAD points to?

Tags: git

Our host lets us deploy using git push, to any branch. It looks like a few extra branches have been pushed to the host by mistake. Before I remove all the extra branches, I would like to double check which branch contains the current state of our live code, i.e. which branch remote head is currently at.

I've tried `git branch -rv --list`, but that just lists remote branches without showing head. I tried `git log production --all --decorate --oneline`, but that is showing me the local "production" branch, not all branches on the "production" remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
git checkout production
git branch -r --contains HEAD
```

In order to [list all remote branches referencing HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309).