# Detached head - move to more recent commit

Tags: git

When in detached mode in git, it is easy to see the older commits with `git log` and so you can easily navigate to them. However how do you move to a more recent one?

Comment: Do you want to switch to one of previous commits?

Comment: If you know the commit hash you can checkout on it even though it's more recent than the state you are in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [list the branches that contain the commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309) referenced by the [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) (say: `<acommit>`)

```
git branch --contains <acommit>
```

Any `git log <acommit>..<abranch>` would then list more recent commits.

Comment: is there no way of doing this directly? something of the lines <current_commit>+1?

Comment: @Ela a commit can be part of multi branches. You need first to know which branch you want to consider, in order to know what +1 means.