# How to check if a commit has been merged to my current branch - somewhere in time?

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have a random feature/XXXXXXX branch that has some commits and naturally the "develop" branch where those features are eventually merged.

How do I check if a certain old commit (e.g. commit ab123456 from branch feature/user-registration) has been somehow brought/merged to my currently active branch (e.g. develop)? Either by directly merging the feature branch to develop or by going up/merged through some other intermediary branch.

Through git commands or through SourceTree UI, both ways are equally suitable for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Solution

You can ask git directly, which (local) branches contain your commit, like so:

```
git branch --contains ab123456
```

use the "-r" option to query for remote branches, like so:

```
git branch -r --contains ab123456
```

#### References

As Andrew C. comments, this is practically a duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit) correctly and elaborately answered by VonC.

#### Note

I now see that Sulli also provides the same answer in this thread.

Comment: Why does this return the help page when the commit id doesn't exist?

Comment: Tip: `git branch branch-name --contains ab123456` will tell you if `branch-name` branch has it.

Comment: But doesn't this only work if the satellite branch was rebased onto the trunk branch? If it was *merged*, the trunk branch will contain the changes but not contain the commit.

Answer (score 6):

Using the following command:

```
git branch --contains <commit-id>
```

This will output every branch which contain the commit. So if your current branch has it, it should appear in the output.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
git log --oneline devBranch..featureBranch
```

You see all commits present in featureBranch and not in devBranch