# How to know the branch name of a commit

Tags: git, gitkraken

In GitKraken, we report from one branch to another commits with the same reference.

**Problem :** It's difficult to detect in which branch the commit is located if we do a search with CTRL+F.

**Is there a way to know the name of the branch from a commit?**

---

We have 7 commits with the same reference 
[image]

If I select one of them, I'm positioned on a commit.
From this view, it is impossible for me to know the name of the branch.
[image]

Comment: Commits are not on branches. This is a misunderstanding of the branch metaphor in git. In *some* contexts, yes, you will have a branch contaning a given commit. But you could also have multiple branches equally relevant, or none. You're searching for *the* name of *the* branch but this is not a given.

Comment: Are all your commit message only a reference such as **HMER-B6WLDS**?

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @padawin Yes and they do not necessarily have the same content, the change depends on the version of the application.

Comment: Commits are not on branches. - That is quite beside the point of the question. Gitkraken has drawn the commit as a circle, on a line which is a branch, and the desire is to know what branch that line is representing. One can scroll up and up and up and try and keep an eye on the gold line and eventually find it, and there it is, the name of the branch. It is a perfectly valid question of gitkraken, if we can learn that without paging up. On which branch is this "graph rendered" commit? That is a question with one unique answer in the gitkraken context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

As @RomainValeri said in his comment: a commit does not "belong" to any branch. A branch is nothing more than a pointer to a commit. There may be a hundred branches from which a commit is reachable, or there may be none.

The git command `git branch --contains <commit>`, suggested by @MohammadAnsari, will show you a list of all branches from which the commit is reachable.

As to GitKraken: There is no immediate solution for your problem. If the commit is further down the graph, it's hard to tell to which strain of ancestor commits it leads. Also, there is no GitKraken command that does what `git branch --contains <commit>` does (or none I know of).

Maybe you should overthink your wokflow of having commits with the same name, or rethink your branching strategy. Do you have several long running branches? If all branches would converge against a single `master`, the question would be trivial.

Comment: As you point out, it is difficult to get the name of the branch if it is far enough from the end (like my screenshot).
We have several branches "Releases" and only one master branch.
All our developments are on the master branch and some commits are cherrypick (or adapted) in other branch (which are different versions to maintain).
The best solution for us was to have additional information on the commit panel on the right "Related branch: ..." or something like that.
I hope the explanations are clear.

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
 git branch --contains <commit>
```

And read this:
[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit/1419637)

Comment: Thank you, this is a good workaround but I would have to make this command on each commit to know the related branch. Is it possible to know this directly from GitKraken?

Comment: This isn't a "workaround", it's how Git works. Like RomainValeri says above, Git commits aren't on or in branches.

Comment: It is a workaround if you're not using the command line, as OP seemingly does.

Comment: We are not using the command line method, some of us have no knowledge of the git and use everything in GUI with GitKraken.

Answer (score 2):

For a commit `$commit`, to find the branches that exactly point at it:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" --points-at $commit
```

And to find the branches from which it is reachable:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" --contains $commit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it if you know the commit id.
Use "ctrl+f" and it will open "Search Commits" dialog where you need to enter commit id.
After you press enter, the tree graph will navigate to that commit and you can see visually on which branch it is placed.

Answer (score -1):

I am definitely the less knowledgeable in git from all of you here, but what about:

1. copying the given commit hash
2. running `git show [commit-hash]` in a git bash
3. the beginning of the (long) output should look like

[image]

The info displayed at origin/version-210627 seems to show the branch (version-210627 in my case).