# Git Commit belongingness to a particular branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I am on `master` branch with 7 commits (say) and moved to commit No. 4 using '`git checkout <commit_hash>`' with HEAD being in detached state now.

I made 3 new commits from commit No. 4 with detached HEAD and created a new branch '`dev`' there.
Then I checked out to `dev` and again made a new commit.

Now can I say that all the commits from this `dev` branch tip commit till root commit of the project belong to `dev` branch or only the `dev` tip commit and previous commit belong to `dev` branch?

What is the concept of belongingness of commits to a branch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "belongingness" is: any commit reachable from `dev` HEAD.

So all commits from `dev` and the one from `master` from which `dev` was created.
See my previous answer "[How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309)", using [`git branch --contains`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---containsltcommitgt):

> With `--contains`, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit)

```
m--m--m--m1--m--m
         \
          d1--d--d--d
```

- `git branch --contain m1` would display both `dev` and `master`
- `git branch --contain d1` would display only `dev`