# How to check branch was already merged to some other branch?

Tags: git

How to check branch was already merged to some other branch/branches and get a list of these branches?

**Update:**

Attached 'duplicate' answer is about how to check which branches merged to a specific branch, i.e. knowing the name of the branch `git branch --merged <my_branch_name>` but I want the opposite: a list of branches where a specific branch was merged into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: If you merge `foo` into `bar`, and then branch `baz` and `qux` off of `bar`, you want those listed as well? Then see duplicate, find which branches contain a certain _commit_. Just use the last commit on the branch of interest.