# How to get the list of merged branches after a specific git tag?

Tags: git

I can see branches of merged commits on my master branch since the last tag like this:
`git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline`
[image]
But I cannot extract branch names from the above command, because it just includes commits when I write the output to a file. I also tried `git branch -r --merged` which is closer to what I want but how can I get only branches after a specific tag?

Comment: Note that those branches aren't branches that were _merged_, they are branches who's HEAD is the same as the commit. They _might_ represent a branch that was merged (in cases where the target branch was fast-forwarded, so the commits match), but it will typically exclude merges that required a merge commit, and will usually also include branches that have not been merged.

Comment: *After* is a tricky word, but `git branch --contains` takes an optional argument; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419623/1256452

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica yes all the branches are merged with the fast-forward method and I'm just looking for merged branches.

Comment: @torek But I don't have the commit hash value, the only thing I can search for is the CHAL number in the branch name (as you see in the attached photo, all the branches start like this: CHAL-[number]+). And CHAL numbers are the main things I want to extract from branch names. But when I do `git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline | grep "CHAL-"`, it doesn't return those branches. It's weird that I see them, but they're not in the printed output of the command itself.

Comment: I cannot see *anything* in the attached photo (which is why photos instead of cut-and-pasted text are generally a bad idea). However, if you want to inspect branch names, use either the user-facing `git branch` (which lists them) or `git for-each-ref` (which is the plumbing command to iterate through *refs*, of which branch names are a particular subset—namely those refs that start with `refs/heads/`).

Comment: @torek That command gives me all the branches but how can I get branches after a specific tag?

Comment: The word *after* is a problem: do you mean after by date-and-time-stamp, or after by graph-position / parent-child-relationship? If the latter, you want `git branch --contains` or its for-each-ref equivalent. You do not need a hash value: `git branch --contains <tagname>` works just fine, doing the same thing as if you had run `git rev-parse <tagname>^{commit}` first to *get* a hash value, then doing `git branch --contains <hash>`.

Comment: thank you @torek, `git branch -r --contains tags/<tagname>` actually does the job.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you what all branches merged into `master` form tag `TagFrom` to `TagTo`:

`git log --oneline --merges --date-order TagFrom..TagTo | sed "s/ Merge branch '/|/;s/.*/|&|/;s/' into 'master'//"`

or you can get form date when the last tag:

`git log -1 --format=%ai MY_TAG_NAME`
e.g.: `git log -1 --format=%ai MT_TAG_NAME`

(this will generate the time of last tag pushed)

Use that time to find the list of all commits from teams.

`git log --after="2018-08-02" --merges --name-only --decorate --first-parent --pretty=format:%s`

Comment: this didn't work for me, I add more info to my question