# How to list old branches that are already fully included in HEAD

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

We have a big `git` repo with lots of history and remote `origin` contains lots of branches that are already included in `master`. **Is there any simple way to list local and remote branches that are already included in HEAD?**

I know that [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419623/334451) helps if I want to do reverse, checking  which branches already contain the commit HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A quick cheat sheet:**

```
git branch -a --merged HEAD
```

will list **all *branches* (local and remote) that are already fully included in `HEAD`**.  This can be used to list old branch labels that may be removed. Note that it will also list the currently checked out branch (marked with asterisk) so you probably shouldn't blindly remove all those branches. (This is the exact answer to original question, see below for additional info.)

---

```
git branch -a --contains HEAD
```

will do the reverse. It will **list all *branches* that already contain the *commit* `HEAD`** meaning those branches are logically forward in the DAG. This can be used to list branches that *include* a given commit (e.g. bugfix).

---

```
git branch -a --no-merged HEAD
```

will list all *branches* (local and remote) that are **not yet included in `HEAD`**. This can be used to list branches that probably contain code that's still missing from `HEAD`.

---

```
git branch -a --no-contains HEAD
```

will **list all *branches* that do not yet include the *commit* `HEAD`**. This can be used to list branches that are *missing* a given commit (e.g. bugfix).

---

(If you're interested in local branches only, remove the flag `-a` the example commands. If you're only interested in remote branches, replace flag `-a` with `-r`. Flag `-a` means all branches, `-r` means remote branches.)