# gh command line fetch the comment for a git commit by its hash

Tags: github, github-cli

How to fetch the github comment associated with the commit hash on a project?

Lets say we have this github commit
https://github.com/actions/checkout/commit/5126516654c75f76bca1de45dd82a3006d8890f9

How to fetch its comments using command line gh command? Github cli?
https://github.com/cli/cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) approach, using the [get commit API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#get-a-commit=):

```
get /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}
```

```sh
gh api repos/actions/checkout/commits/5126516654c75f76bca1de45dd82a3006d8890f9 \
       --jq ".commit.message"
```

Result:

```
Bump minimist from 1.2.5 to 1.2.6 (#741)

Bumps [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) from 1.2.5 to 1.2.6.
- [Release notes](https://github.com/substack/minimist/releases)
- [Commits](https://github.com/substack/minimist/compare/1.2.5...1.2.6)

---
updated-dependencies:
- dependency-name: minimist
  dependency-type: indirect
...

Signed-off-by: dependabot[bot] <support@github.com>

Co-authored-by: dependabot[bot] <49699333+dependabot[bot]@users.noreply.github.com>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to get the branch that this commit is in?

Comment: @Phil I mentioned in 2009 [`git branch --contain xxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309) as a way to get the branch for a given commit.