# Run job only when push to develop or tag on main

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure my **first** gitlab ci.
My idea is to build a docker image only when I create tag on the main branch with git tag as a docker tag or when I do a push to develop.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
# global variables - can't be change using before_script
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: "backupchecker"
  PORTAINER_WEBHOOK_KEY: "b1b9c532-0cfa-609b-92dc-7af3767bd9a1"

# variables
before_script:
  - apk --no-cache add git
  # bet branch name
  - git fetch &> /dev/null
  - CI_COMMIT_BRANCHES=$(git for-each-ref | grep $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep /remotes/origin/ | sed "s/.*\///")
  - >
    for CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in $CI_COMMIT_BRANCHES; do
      export BRANCH=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    done

  - |
    if [ "$BRANCH" == "main" ] && [ -n "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]; then
      export IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_TAG
    else
      export IMAGE_TAG="${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}-latest"
    fi

    #if on main and there is a tag or on develop and there is push
  - |
    if [ "$BRANCH" == "main" ] && [ $CI_COMMIT_TAG ]; then
      export BUILD="true"
    elif [ "$BRANCH" == "develop" ] && [ $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" ]; then
      export BUILD="true"
    else
      export BUILD="false"
    fi

  - echo $BUILD
  - echo $IMAGE_TAG

stages:
  - build
  - push
  - deploy

build_image:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop" || $CI_COMMIT_TAG) && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /(no|skip)-build/'
  script:
    - docker build -t ${docker_registry}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} -f BackupChecker/Dockerfile .

push_image:
  stage: push
  rules:
    - if: '($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop" || $CI_COMMIT_TAG) && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /(no|skip)-build/'
  script:
    - docker login ${docker_registry} -u docker -p ${docker_registry_pass}
    - docker push ${docker_registry}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}

portainer:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /(no|skip)-(build|deploy)/'
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  script:
    - 'curl -X POST "https://portainer.example.com/api/webhooks/${PORTAINER_WEBHOOK_KEY}"'
```

in global `before_script` section I'm getting the branch name (I have no idea if there is a better way) and based on that I'm creating `IMAGE_TAG` variable.
I'm also setting `BUILD` variable.

I've tried using `BRANCH` or `BUILD` in rules, but when I add those variables my jobs are skipped.

How can I run `build_image` and `push_image` only when: push is done to develop OR tag is created on main?

The worst part is getting the branch name when I create tag, because according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not available when in tag pipeline.

I've checked multiple questions, some of them suggested using multiple if's in rules, but please remember that the problemsare:

- to get the branch name when creating tag
- use variables set in before_script in rules

Answer (score 1):

> use variables set in before_script in rules

This is not possible because all `rules:` are evaluated on the GitLab server in order to create the pipeline in the first place. Therefore, you cannot use variables created in a job in `rules:` in the same pipeline.

> to get the branch name when creating tag

This is not really a thing because tags are not associated with branches in the first place; tags are only associated with commits. When you push a tag, the push event does not contain any branch information and the tag itself does not contain any branch information. That's just kind of how git works.

Technically you can use `git` to determine which branches (if any) contain the commit associated with the tag. (See for example: [How to list branches that contain a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)) -- Unfortunately, GitLab does not make this information available in a way that it can be used with `rules:` -- even though you might be able to use a script to determine what you want to know, as mentioned previously, `rules:` are evaluated before the pipeline is even created, so you can't run a script to determine this then use it in `rules:`

---

The only workaround that might be possible would be to use a parent pipeline to calculate the information you want in a job, then [trigger a child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html), passing the variables that can subsequently be used in `rules:` in the child pipeline.

As a generic example, your parent pipeline yaml may contain something like this:

```yaml
calculate_something:
  # calculate a value so it can be passed to the trigger job
  # for the sake of the demo, it's just a static value
  # you would need to implement a script to generate the value(s) you want
  script:
    - something="value"
    - echo "SOMETHING=$something" > vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

trigger_downstream:
  needs: [calculate_something]
  variables:  # gets the value from dotenv artifact
    SOMETHING: $SOMETHING
  # trigger another pipeline that can use `$SOMETHING` in its `rules:`
  trigger:
    include: downstream.gitlab-ci.yml
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
    strategy: depend
```

Which will allow the child pipeline defined in `downstream.gitlab-ci.yml` to make use of the dynamically generated variable value from the parent pipeline's `calculate_something` job in its `rules:`

```yaml
some_job:
  rules:
    - if: $SOMETHING == "value"
  script:
    - echo '$SOMETHING was "value"'

another_job:
  rules:
    - if: $SOMETHING != "value"
  script:
    - echo '$SOMETHING was not "value" it was "'"$SOMETHING\""
```

Applying this to your case, you can use `git` commands (or GitLab API calls) to calculate whether the commit associated with a tag is present on the `main` branch and pass that information to the downstream pipeline:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
check_if_tag_is_on_main:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script: 
    - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
    - git fetch origin
    - tag_branches="$(git branch -a --contains $CI_COMMIT_SHA)"
    - |
      if grep -E '^(\*)?(\s+)?(remotes/origin/)?main$' <<< $tag_branches; then
          tag_on_main="true"
      else
          tag_on_main="false"
      fi
    - echo "TAG_ON_MAIN=$tag_on_main" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

trigger_downstream:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  needs: [check_if_tag_is_on_main]
  variables:
    TAG_ON_MAIN: $TAG_ON_MAIN
  trigger:
    include: downstream.gitlab-ci.yml
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true
    strategy: depend
```

```yaml
# downstram.gitlab-ci.yml
some_job:
  rules:
    - if: $TAG_ON_MAIN == "true"
  script:
    - echo "tag was on main"
    - echo "tag ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"

another_job:
  rules:
    - if: $TAG_ON_MAIN != "true"
  script:
    - echo "tag was not on main"
    - echo "tag ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
```

If you don't want to use the child pipeline approach, you could also just not use `rules:` altogether and just evaluate this in the pipeline. You could use the same script logic for checking if the branch is on `main` and simply `exit 0` if it's not.

```
job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  needs: [check_if_tag_is_on_main]
  script:
    - if [ "$TAG_ON_MAIN" != "true" ]; then exit 0; fi
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I was able to add branch calculation logic in global `before_script`, in the last step I'm calling `exit 0` when my conditions are not fulfilled.