# PS1 line with Git current branch and colors

Tags: git, command-prompt, bash

Here is my current PS1:

```
export PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

How can I display the current branch in a different color?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can wrap the part that you want in colour with the following:

`\e[0;32m` - sets colour (in this case, to green)

`\e[m` - sets colour back to the default

For example, this sets the prompt to the last token of the current path, in green, followed by `$` in the default colour:

```
export PS1='\e[0;32m\w\e[m $'
```

Other colours are available too. Have a look at [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) under colorization for a comprehensive list of alternatives.

Comment: It should be noted that it is best to wrap the colour codes between `\[` and `\]`, otherwise you could end up having problems with a long command line not wrapping correctly because bash counts the wrong number of characters: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line

Comment: [This](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) is a really good source for bash prompt coloring as well

Comment: Also I *strongly* encourage **not** to hardcode color codes. Use `$(tput setaf 2)` (2 for green, 1 for red, 3 for yellow, etc), `$(tput bold)` for bold and `$(tput sgr0)` to reset. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037 . And use the suggested `\[` and `\]` if assigning to `PS1`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: Just like @Kjir said, to avoid having problems with a long command line not wrapping correctly, the most correct is: `export PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] $ '`

Answer (score 150):

Here is, part by part (and no Ruby):

```
function color_my_prompt {
    local __user_and_host="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h"
    local __cur_location="\[\033[01;34m\]\w"
    local __git_branch_color="\[\033[31m\]"
    #local __git_branch="\`ruby -e \"print (%x{git branch 2> /dev/null}.grep(/^\*/).first || '').gsub(/^\* (.+)$/, '(\1) ')\"\`"
    local __git_branch='`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`'
    local __prompt_tail="\[\033[35m\]$"
    local __last_color="\[\033[00m\]"
    export PS1="$__user_and_host $__cur_location $__git_branch_color$__git_branch$__prompt_tail$__last_color "
}
color_my_prompt
```

Looks like this (with my own terminal palette):

[image: Colored prompt]

Also, see [this](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/setting-up-git-prompt-step-by-step/) and [this](http://niczsoft.com/2010/05/my-git-prompt/) article.

Comment: @AhmedFasih - I've added a dirty state variable to mine: ``local __git_dirty='`git rev-parse 2>/dev/null && (git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code 2> /dev/null || echo -e \*)`'``

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 27):

Here is my PS1 line:

```
\n\[\e[1;37m\]|-- \[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;39m\]@\[\e[1;36m\]\h\[\e[0;39m\]:\[\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[0;39m\]\[\e[1;35m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\[\e[0;39m\] \[\e[1;37m\]--|\[\e[0;39m\]\n$
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

```
function pc {
  [ -d .git ] && git name-rev --name-only @
}
PS1='\e];\s\a\n\e[33m\w \e[36m$(pc)\e[m\n$ '
```

[image: ps1]

[Source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/8a8b368717daecb5400de5/.bashrc)

Comment: This does only show the git branch in the root folder of the git repository

Comment: since git worktrees are a thing and result in `.git` being a file a `[ -r .git ]` might be an improvement for some.

Answer (score 13):

This is my PS1 solution.

It looks great on a Mac with the Novel theme.
Sorry, but my indentation got munged a bit. Hack it till you like it.

```
function we_are_in_git_work_tree {
    git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null
}

function parse_git_branch {
    if we_are_in_git_work_tree
    then
    local BR=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
    if [ "$BR" == HEAD ]
    then
        local NM=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD 2> /dev/null)
        if [ "$NM" != undefined ]
        then echo -n "@$NM"
        else git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null
        fi
    else
        echo -n $BR
       fi
    fi
}

function parse_git_status {
    if we_are_in_git_work_tree
    then
    local ST=$(git status --short 2> /dev/null)
    if [ -n "$ST" ]
    then echo -n " + "
    else echo -n " - "
    fi
    fi
}

function pwd_depth_limit_2 {
    if [ "$PWD" = "$HOME" ]
    then echo -n "~"
    else pwd | sed -e "s|.*/\(.*/.*\)|\1|"
    fi
}

COLBROWN="\[\033[1;33m\]"
COLRED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
COLCLEAR="\[\033[0m\]"

# Export all these for subshells
export -f parse_git_branch parse_git_status we_are_in_git_work_tree pwd_depth_limit_2
export PS1="$COLRED<$COLBROWN \$(pwd_depth_limit_2)$COLRED\$(parse_git_status)$COLBROWN\$(parse_git_branch) $COLRED>$COLCLEAR "
export TERM="xterm-color"
```

If you are checked out at a branch, you get the branch name.

If you are in a just init'd Git project, you just get '@'.

If you are headless, you get a nice human name relative to some branch or tag, with an '@' preceding the name.

If you are headless and not an ancestor of some branch or tag you just get the short SHA1.

In addition, a red '-' signifies a clean work directory and index, and a red '+' signifies the opposite.

Comment: This is nice, but for me on a mac it doesn't update when I switch branches.  Having difficulties getting it to delay evaluation. +1 for readability.

Comment: @darKoram: You probably need to escape a `$` with a ` \ `.

Comment: Awesome, Ill hack it around but taht was more or less, what i was looking for! +1 from me:)

Comment: These days I'd just recommend powerline. There are (at least) python, go and rust versions.

Comment: On your recommendation, I got Powerline (`python3 -m pip install powerline-status`) up and running in iTerm2 in a short amount of time.  I think I like it!

Answer (score 11):

#### My uber-powerful multi-line Linux prompt!

Put it either in your .bashrc or better: save it in /etc/bash-prompt and source it from your .bashrc.
Using tput is supposed to be the right way to do colors.

```
#!/bin/bash

set_prompt()
{
   local last_cmd=$?
   local txtreset='$(tput sgr0)'
   local txtbold='$(tput bold)'
   local txtblack='$(tput setaf 0)'
   local txtred='$(tput setaf 1)'
   local txtgreen='$(tput setaf 2)'
   local txtyellow='$(tput setaf 3)'
   local txtblue='$(tput setaf 4)'
   local txtpurple='$(tput setaf 5)'
   local txtcyan='$(tput setaf 6)'
   local txtwhite='$(tput setaf 7)'
   # unicode "✗"
   local fancyx='\342\234\227'
   # unicode "✓"
   local checkmark='\342\234\223'
   # Line 1: Full date + full time (24h)
   # Line 2: current path
   PS1="\[$txtbold\]\[$txtwhite\]\n\D{%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S}\n\[$txtgreen\]\w\n"
   # User color: red for root, yellow for others
   if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]; then
       PS1+="\[$txtred\]"
   else
       PS1+="\[$txtyellow\]"   
   fi
   # Line 3: user@host
   PS1+="\u\[$txtwhite\]@\h\n"
   # Line 4: a red "✗" or a green "✓" and the error number
   if [[ $last_cmd == 0 ]]; then
      PS1+="\[$txtgreen\]$checkmark \[$txtwhite\](0)"
   else
      PS1+="\[$txtred\]$fancyx \[$txtwhite\]($last_cmd)"
   fi
   # Line 4: green git branch
   PS1+="\[$txtgreen\]$(__git_ps1 ' (%s)')\[$txtwhite\]"
   # Line 4: good old prompt, $ for user, # for root
   PS1+=" \\$ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='set_prompt'
```

Comment: Nice one, +1. I am still looking for one which would display the current user.name.

Comment: Try adding this somewhere in your prompt:  $(git config --global --get user.name)

Comment: If you want the /current/ user.name, why would you pull from the --global config?

Comment: Would you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: @YuriGhensev: you need to source git-prompt.sh. For my distro (Archlinux) its location is: /usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh, on other distros it's somewhere else (it can even have another filename) and you might have to install some extra git package.

Comment: Please note that this way of using `fancyx` will destroy your multiline prompt (same as when not escaping colors correctly https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly). Looks like bash in not really good in understanding characters wide. So simple workaround will be to enclose 2 of 3 parts of those wide symbold into `\[\]`

Comment: @VonC Take a look at my answer above, it includes the username.

Comment: @VonC To be fair I posted that about three years ago! ;)

Comment: @DanL And you waited all that time to tell me? Sorry I missed it at the time!

Answer (score 5):

1. Add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

2. Restart the terminal, or source `~/.bashrc`:

[image]

More detail: https://medium.com/@thucnc/how-to-show-current-git-branch-with-colors-in-bash-prompt-380d05a24745

Comment: This is broken because of the double quotes. See e.g. @ryanpcmcquen's answer for a fixed version.

Answer (score 4):

For my Mac with the Homebrew theme, this works really well. Fully debugged and very fast, and completely self-contained.
BONUS: Smart enough to ONLY show a git branch as part of the prompt when you're actually *in* a git repo! :)

```
# Color prompt for git
reset=$(tput sgr0)
boldgreen=$(tput setaf 2)$(tput bold)
cyan=$(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 6)
boldred=$(tput setaf 1)$(tput bold)
boldwhite=$(tput setaf 7)$(tput bold)
boldyellow=$(tput setaf 3)$(tput bold)

PARENCLR=$'\001\e[0;36m\002'
BRANCHCLR=$'\001\e[1;33m\002'

alias branchname="git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -ne 's/^* \(.*\)/ ${PARENCLR}(${BRANCHCLR}\1${PARENCLR}\)/p'"

GIT_STATUS='$(branchname)'

PROMPT_CHAR="\$"
PS1="\[$boldgreen\]\u\[$cyan\]::\[$boldred\]\h \[$cyan\]{\[$boldwhite\].../\W\[$cyan\]}\[$reset\]$GIT_STATUS\[$reset\]$PROMPT_CHAR "
```

Here's what it looks like:
[Mac + Homebrew + Color Git Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2p3A.png)

If you want to have the full path (or remove the .../), then just change the -W to -w (and remove the .../).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at liquidprompt:

https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt

Maybe a bit too heavy for your requirements, but you can switch features off by setting

`LP_ENABLE_...=0`

See the documentation on above page.

Answer (score 3):

Modified version of @cmcginty's prompt that adds in the `git` parsing function and uses slightly different spacing:

```
# So I know where I am in repos:
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

# Modified from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4138531/2662028
export PS1='\n\[\e[1;37m\]|-- \[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;39m\]@\[\e[1;36m\]\h\[\e[0;39m\]:\[\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[0;39m\]\[\e[1;35m\]$(parse_git_branch " (%s)")\[\e[0;39m\] \[\e[1;37m\]--|\[\e[0;39m\]\n\$ '
```

This also uses `\$` in the prompt instead of `$`, which means you will get `#` when you are root.

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke `tput` with the appropriate parameters. See the `tput(1)` and `terminfo(5)` man pages.

Comment: I think I'm not escaping the tput call correctly. Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Fernando: Be sure to wrap your `tput` command in `\[` and `\]` so the characters it outputs are not counted in the length of the prompt. This will keep the prompt from getting messed up when you scroll through history, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine

```
export PS1="\n\[\033[1;30m\][$$:$PPID - \j:\!\[\033[1;30m\]]\[\033[0;36m\] \T \
\[\033[1;30m\][\[\033[1;34m\]\u@\H\[\033[1;30m\]:\[\033[0;37m\]${SSH_TTY:-o} \
\[\033[0;32m\]+${SHLVL}\[\033[1;30m\]] \[\033[1;37m\]\w\[\033[0;37m\]\[\033[1;34m\]\$(__git_ps1 \" (%s)\") \[\033[0;37m\] \n\$ "
```

Comment: can you explain the components ?

Answer (score 0):

For more complicated status of Git you can use [some larger script](http://niczsoft.com/2010/05/my-git-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

This PS1 will color your current git branch in yellow:

```
export PS1="\[\033[38;5;11m\]\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]@\h:\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;6m\][\w]\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;226m\]($(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2))\[$(tput sgr0)\]: \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

To see in a more interactive way the how the building of a PS1 string can be done (other ways are possible obviously), here the link to a very handy PS1 string generator for your .bashrc. I used it for the string above:

http://bashrcgenerator.com/

It solves in a simple way your question and more generally the issue of building of a customized and colorized shell prompt, including the current git branch

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this:

```
eyes=(O o ∘ ◦ ⍤ ⍥)
en=${#eyes[@]}
mouth='_'
linesymbol='-'

RED='\e[31m'
GRN='\e[32m'
YLW='\e[33m'
BLU='\e[34m'
MGN='\e[35m'
DEF='\e[0m'
BLD='\e[1m'
DIM='\e[2m'

face () { # gen random face
    [[ $error -gt 0 ]] && ecolor=$RED || ecolor=$YLW
    [[ $1 ]] && printf "${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$mouth${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}" \
             || printf "$ecolor${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$YLW$mouth$ecolor${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$DEF"
}

info () { error=$? git_tst= git_clr=
    [[ -d .git ]] && {
         git_tst=($(git -c color.ui=never  status -sb)) git_tst="GIT ${git_tst[*]} " # Test output
         git_clr=($(git -c color.ui=always status -sb)) git_clr="GIT ${git_clr[*]} " # Colored output
    }
    [[ $debian_chroot ]] && chrt="($debian_chroot)" || chrt=  # If in chroot
    name_length="{ $HOSTNAME$chrt }"
    name_length=${#name_length}
    face_tst='O_o  o_O'
    top_line_left=$[(COLUMNS-name_length)/2]
    top_line_right=$[COLUMNS-(top_line_left+name_length)]
    printf -v top_line "%${top_line_left}s{_S_$DEF$BLD$HOSTNAME$chrt${DEF}_S_$GRN}%${top_line_right}s"
    printf -v bot_line "%${COLUMNS}s"
    printf -v date  "%(%a %d %b %T)T"
    top_line=${top_line// /-}
    top_line=$GRN${top_line//_S_/ }$DEF
    bot_line=$GRN${bot_line// /-}$DEF
    spaces=$[COLUMNS-${#date}-${#PWD}-${#git_tst}-${#face_tst}]; ((spaces<0)) && spaces=1
    printf "$top_line\n$(face) $BLD$BLU$PWD$DEF%${spaces}s$git_clr$DIM$date $(face)\n$bot_line"
}


PS1='\n$(info)\n$ '
case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*) PS1="\[\e]0;$(face 1) \h\w\a\]$PS1";; esac
```

This code is supposed to go to `~/.bashrc`. The result looks like this:

[image: info bar]

Code is available [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/info-bar)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Windows/Cygwin/Bash solution.

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file.

xxx is the location of your local Git repository.

```
GetBranch()
{
    cat /cygdrive/c/xxx/.git/HEAD | sed 's+^ref: refs/heads/++'
}
export PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[36m\]\$(GetBranch) \[\e[33m\]\w \[\e[0m\] \n\$ "
```

Comment: -1 for hardcoded path to the repository. This would work for one repository only, so its usability is in theory only.