# GitBash generally slow

Tags: git, performance

Ever since I installed GitBash on my computer, the prompt has been very unresponsive. I think I have lowered the culprit down to the command `__git_ps1`.

The timings for this command are as follows, along with the output:

```
$ time __git_ps1
+ __git_ps1
+ local pcmode=no
+ local detached=no
+ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
+ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
+ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
+ case "$#" in
+ printf_format=' (%s)'
+ local ps1_expanded=yes
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '3.1.20(4)-release' ']'
+ shopt -q promptvars
+ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-
work-tree --short HEAD
+ repo_info=
+ rev_parse_exit_code=128
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' no = yes ']'
+ return

real    0m0.541s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.358s
```

$PS1 is equal to `\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$`

I don't have this issue on any of my other computers either. I've virtualized windows 7 8.1 and 10 and they all don't have this issue. Any insight onto this issue will be helpful

`time git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD` on my computer:

```
real    0m0.364s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.186s
```

Above command in VM:

```
real    0m0.031s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: Does your current directory affect the speed? The time is probably all spent in git rev-parse HEAD. I've seen performance issues with git in the status line with large repositories.

Comment: Can you time the `git rev-parse` command in a couple of repositories on your various VMs? Try to use the same repos/clones for the tests. This should give you an indication on whether it's related to the VM, the repo or maybe the version of Git you're using.

Comment: @lunixbochs The current directory does not affect the speed

Comment: @nwinkler Updated to show timings

Comment: Run the same `git rev-parse` command with `strace -r` before it.

Comment: @lunixbochs I'm getting a "Command not found. I'm executing `$ time strace -r git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD`

Comment: `strace` only works on Linux. If you're on OS X or BSD, you'll need to use `dtruss` instead.

Comment: @lunixbochs GitBash doesn't have `dtruss` either

Comment: Oh, is GitBash a Windows thing? It's going to be hard for you to debug. Try "Process Monitor" from SysInternals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git/Bash is extremely slow in Windows 7 x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64)  - -  try `git config --global core.fscache true`, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows installation for any process trackers.
They are corporate installed services/agents that track every process launch for compliance reasons.  Example: Altiris.
Work with your compliance group to get exclusions for git/bash/cygwin, etc...
Get either exclusions, or changes in how these processes get logged (asych vs. sync).
Good luck if your firm uses these.