# SourceTree very slow with many repositories

Tags: git, performance, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

I work on a lot of small projects on daily basis and need to switch often.

- I have over 50 Git Repositories in Sourcetree.
- Usually 5 projects are open in "Tabs".

Switching from "Tab" in SourceTree is very slow. Sometimes up to 15 seconds. How can I improve this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it helps others, but I use VMware. In similar situations, I experienced slow performance until I disabled the 'Accelerate 3D Graphics' option in the VMware settings, and surprisingly, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but you could also try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045966/371917

```
$ git config --global core.preloadindex true
$ git config --global core.fscache true
$ git config --global gc.auto 256
```

Secondly, here is a post that explains that `git gc --aggressive` [may not be a great idea](https://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/).

Comment: Looks like the first two are now enabled by default if you have a new'ish version of `git`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't fix the performance, barely I can switch between branches. This issue occurred with the latest version of SourceTree

Comment: @Lunatikul it could also be an issue specific to the latest version of SourceTree. Perhaps wait for an update and try again?

Comment: Was Bitdefender Issue

Answer (score 22):

Executing the stated git command did not do the trick for me. Eventually what really speed up SourceTree was **disabling 'spell check commit messages'** in the tools > options menu. I also disabled 'load avatar images from gravatar.com' option while I was at it.

Comment: The performance when switching projects decreased mysteriously one day (without any change in the loaded repositories). Disabling the spell check fixed it for me. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Disabling gravatar did it! Wow. Big difference.

Answer (score 12):

Any action in my source tree was super slow. Commit, click on a file to see changes, push etc.

I discovered that my antivirus (avast) was the cause. I disabled the file protection and source tree became immediate.

Comment: I discovered it went so much faster with Avast enabled, but wasn't sure why. Thought maybe it was the firewall, but added an exclusion for file protection to my working folders and SourceTree is responsive again. And as a bonus my local webhost environment is fast again too!

Comment: wow, this is even the same for Mac. I downloaded `bitdefender` for the shake of testing antivirus on Mac and my ST became super slow. Thank a ton !!!

Comment: I had the same problem, SourceTree was being that slow that was impossible to use. It started after I updated to Windows 10, I noticed everything involving the file system was really slow (specially my second hard drive). I was blaming Windows at the beginning but It seems Avast and its "file system shield" was provoking that. I disabled it and everything works well again!

Comment: windows defender is among the culprits

Comment: You are right Emir, you saved me so much time! Thank you! It was Avast causing this problem (e.g. I was waiting for 5 mniutes to pull the code from repository). I disabled "file system shield" (Štít souborového systému) and there is no prbolem with sourcetree anymore.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem too. I also have avast and this worked for me and might work for you and maybe a different AV. But I added the C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\
to my avast exclusions directory and now it is running much faster!

Comment: This solve my same problem.
I haven't Avast but is the same with Windows Defender in Windows 10.
Finally now go fast.
Thanks

Comment: Same happens to me using Bitdefender

Answer (score 7):

For me it was the 'spell check commit messages' option in the settings. Even clicking the tick took 20 sec to process, but it was the last freezing I experienced.

Comment: +1 super random, but I've been having issues since a few builds ago even with just a few repos and this has completely fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

The source tree ticket system has a ticket about a similar bug that was fixed.
http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2015/01/6-month-old-critical-performance-bug-with-sourcetree-is-getting-attention/

I never used so many repos at once and assume that sourcetree is not build to handle this amount of data on every time you switch tabs. I assume sourcetree need to refresh the data and reads and build your data out of the disk page file.

Try to use fewer projects and see it you still have the same problem.

If you still experience lack of performance try to run gc (garbage collector) on your repos and test it again.

`git gc --aggressive` shrinks the repository size.

Comment: 'git gc --aggressive' did not help significant, but it didn't harm either.

Comment: Update: see a slight improvement after 'garbage collection', but not spectacular.

Comment: SourceTree is slow again... I miss the older version :(

Answer (score 4):

Improved performance with

1. Install latest git exe from https://git-scm.com/download/win
2. Configured Options > Git > `Use System Git` instead `Use Embedded Git`

Comment: I already used systems git, but updating from 2.13.2 to 2.20.1 helped. Now SourceTree is a LOT faster than before, where I need to wait several seconds to detect a few changed line on a single file. Can't explain why cause only 3 repos were open and the one I'm currently open is small.

Answer (score 2):

This may help someone else. I was having slow response issues with SourceTree 1.6.x and git 1.9.x. Downgrading git to 1.8.3 and SourceTree to 1.5.2 solved the problem.

Comment: The link for 1.5.2: http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.5.2.exe

Comment: I wrote a long blog post about downgrading, but keeping the embedded git/hg up to date (old git/hg had serious security issues): http://wiert.me/2015/01/15/downgrading-to-sourcetree-1-5-x-from-1-6-x-but-keeping-up-with-the-youngest-embedded-git-and-mercurial/

Comment: Eventually I ended up changing the software to TortoiseGit. SourceTree didn't offer any solution for the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the git folder to an SSD drive, if possible (dramatically improved my SourceTree performance).
2. Avoid having a lot of stashes, which REALLY slows down SourceTree.

Comment: How do I do the first one?

Comment: Deleting stashes helped.  Why though

Comment: Deleting stashes helped me too. However, I only had like 3 stashes across repos.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version currently 2.1.2.5 released June 2017 was running dog slow for me even after trying all the answers here prior to today (even with just 1 project).

Apparently, .gitconfig was written to a network drive (H:) when SourceTree was first installed. This is what got the performance to instantaneous for me:

1. Move .gitconfig to local SSD (C:)
2. Set HOME variable. In Environment Variables (specifically User variable), set HOME to the value of C: (or whatever other path you decide to set).

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:*

**Option 1:** (Keep using SourceTree):
SourceTree does long thorough refresh. Can be turned off by setting filter to "Modified". (For me I had to set it back and forth once to take effect).

[image]

**Option 2:** (Use Tower/CLI and set showUntrackedFiles)

**Option 3:** (Use Tower/CLI and With Scalar).

Microsoft has a solution for improving repo performance: [Scalar](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-scalar/)

**Long Version:**
Had this issue with large repository (has many files). Investigated and found root cause of SourceTree slowness.

You can test issue in command line:

```
git status -uall
```

vs

```
git status -uno
```

If you find git `status -uall` is super slow (same slowness as SourceTree then this is likely your culprit).

Sourcetree always uses `-uall` when doing status refreshes.

There is a way to configure your git config file to always skip searching for untracked files when running `git status` via:

```
git config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

The problem then becomes SourceTree refuses to respect this flag (while other tools like Tower do respect it).

More info can be found here (under `status.showUntrackedFiles` section):
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

And here (under `--untracked-files[=<mode>]` section):
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status

NOTE: Setting `showUntrackedFiles` property to `no` on your repo's git config file will mean when you add a new file it won't be picked up by `git status` unless you explicitly run it with `-uall` param.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had way to many untracked files. Modified my .gitignore and SourceTree stoped being slow