# Why is 'git log' so slow on windows 7 64?

Tags: windows, git

I am using 'git log' on the windows7 command line and it is very slow.

I tried: [Git/Bash is extremely slow in Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64)

but this did not help. How can i speed things up?

Comment: Have you considered installing cygwin and using the cygwin version of git and/or bash?

Comment: I installed lambda cmder is that similar, same issue

Comment: I've not used lambda cmder, so I can't say. I've looked at the source code for cygwin. IMO, it goes to great lengths to be the environment that is closest to linux (i.e. git's [and bash's] bread and butter) and also does its best to be fast. In any case, I'd say the best way is to try it. For me, when I need git, bash, perl(!), etc. ports, I use cygwin. One of the reasons: cygwin's environment. It allows most pgms to be ported with just a recompile. They don't have to get hacked up with #ifdefs, etc. Thus, cygwin can supply almost any utility [the repo has _many_ packages]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue persists with the latest [Git for Windows Git 2.20.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.20.1.windows.1)

And Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) will improve the speed for a particular form of `git log`:
`git log -G<regex>` looked for a hunk in the "`git log -p`" patch output that contained a string that matches the given pattern.
`Optimize this code to ignore binary files`, which by default will not show any hunk that would match any pattern (unless `textconv` or the `--text` option is in effect, that is).

See [commit e0e7cb8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0e7cb8080cb4a0b3a24f288bf363fe517b49790) (14 Dec 2018) by [Thomas Braun (`t-b`)](https://github.com/t-b).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ecdc7cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecdc7cbbac04241f1e5a90fb1fff13cff2ed7a82), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `log -G`: ignore binary files
>
> The `-G<regex>` option of log looks for the differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match regex.
>
> Currently `-G` looks also into patches of binary files (which according to [LibXDiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff.html)) is binary as well.
>
> This has a couple of issues:
>
> - It **makes the pickaxe search slow**.
>     In a proprietary repository of the author with only ~5500 commits and a total `.git` size of ~300MB:
>
> searching takes ~13 seconds
>
> ```
> $time git log -Gwave > /dev/null
> real    0m13,241s
> user    0m12,596s
> sys     0m0,644s
> ```
>
> **whereas when we ignore binary files with this patch it takes ~4s**:
>
> ```
> $time ~/devel/git/git log -Gwave > /dev/null
>
> real    0m3,713s
> user    0m3,608s
> sys     0m0,105s
> ```
>
> which is a speedup of more than fourfold.
>
> - The internally used algorithm for generating patch text is based on
>     xdiff and its states in LibXDiff:
>
> > The output format of the binary patch file is proprietary
> >     (and binary) and it is basically a collection of copy and insert
> >     commands [..]
>
> which means that the current format could change once the internal algorithm is changed as the format is not standardized.
>   In addition the `git` binary patch format used for preparing patches for `git apply` is *different* from the `xdiff` format as can be seen by comparing.
>
> ```
> git log -p -a
>
> commit 6e95bf4bafccf14650d02ab57f3affe669be10cf
>  Author: A U Thor <author@example.com>
>  Date:   Thu Apr 7 15:14:13 2005 -0700
> ```
>
> modify binary file
>
> ```
> diff --git a/data.bin b/data.bin
> index f414c84..edfeb6f 100644
> --- a/data.bin
> +++ b/data.bin
> @@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
>  a
>  a^@A
> +a
> +a^@A
> ```
>
> with `git log --binary`
>
> ```
> commit 6e95bf4bafccf14650d02ab57f3affe669be10cf
> Author: A U Thor <author@example.com>
> Date:   Thu Apr 7 15:14:13 2005 -0700
> ```
>
> modify binary file
>
> ```
> diff --git a/data.bin b/data.bin
> index f414c84bd3aa25fa07836bb1fb73db784635e24b..edfeb6f501[..]
> GIT binary patch
> literal 12
> QcmYe~N@Pgn0zx1O01)N^ZvX%Q
>
> literal 6
> NcmYe~N@Pgn0ssWg0XP5v
> ```
>
> which seems unexpected.
>
> **To resolve these issues this patch makes `-G<regex>` ignore binary files by default**.
>   Textconv filters are supported and also `-a`/`--text` for getting the old and broken behaviour back.
>
> The `-S<block of text>` option of `log` looks for differences that changes the number of occurrences of the specified block of text (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. As we want to keep the current behaviour, add a test to ensure it stays that way.