# Check if directory is git repository (without having to cd into it)

Tags: bash, git, shell

What's a shell command I can use to, using the full directory path, determine whether or not a given directory is a git repository? Specifically, I'd like to be able to do this without being in the directory, and without having to cd into it. I'd also like to be able to do it with a command that returns a simple "true" or "false" (much the way that rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree does), but it's not a requirement.

Comment: `test -d "$path/.git"`

Comment: and also `[[ -d "$PATH/.git" ]] && <other commands>`

Comment: You could grep for a .git folder? Or you could cd into it then check then cd back to current working directory?

Comment: @Siguza I considered that as a solution, but what if the directory isn't actually a git repository, but just contains a directory named .git? (e.g. .git doesn't contain ORIG_HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, etc.)

Comment: @Ataraxia Then I'd consider that a _broken_ git repository... but that is a matter of opinion. If you only want intact/"valid" git repositories, you're probably best off testing a `git` command for error codes in addition to the `.git` check.

Comment: Of course, there could still be a bizarre scenario where `a` is a git repository, `a/b/.git` exists, and testing `a/b` for git-repository-ness would return true. You can mitigate this case by checking parent directories first however.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `git -C <path> rev-parse`. It will return 0 if the directory at `<path>` is a git repository and an error code otherwise.

**Further Reading**:

- [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)
- [`-C <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt)

Comment: Note: This will also return 0 for any subdirectory of a git repository.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!

Comment: `git -C <path> rev-parse 2>/dev/null` for cleaner script integration

Comment: To complement the answer and comments:
`git -C $REPO_DIR rev-parse 2>/dev/null`
`exit_code=$(echo $?)`
`if [ "$exit_code" -ne 0 ] ; then 
    echo "$REPO_DIR is not a git repository"
fi`

Comment: @JBSnorro I hate bash, but I wonder, could you not also simply write `if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ;`?

Comment: @ypnos That opinion is shared. And yes you could write it like that.

Comment: @JBSnorro This is the script in the saner Fish syntax: `if not git -C $REPO_DIR rev-parse 2>/dev/null; echo $REPO_DIR is not a git repository; end`

Comment: Siguza correctly points out that the above command will also return 0 if `<path>` is any subdirectory of a git repository.  If you want to know whether the given path is the **root**, you can use the `--git-dir` option which [turns off the repository discovery](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt), _e.g._ `git -C <path> --git-dir=.git rev-parse 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 6):

We can also try `git status` command and if the output is like :

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Then, the directory is not a git repository.

Answer (score 3):

Any directory in the system could be a git working copy.  You can use an directory as if it contained a `.git` subdirectory by setting the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables to point at an actual `.git` directory and the root of your working copy, or use the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options instead.  See the [git man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_the_git_repository) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Walk's comments, 
`git status` will throw fatal message if its not a repo.
`echo $?` will help to capture of its an ERROR or not.
If its a git repo then `echo $?` will be 0 else 128 will be the value

Answer (score 1):

Consider `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` as well here (with the appropriate `-C` first as well if/as desired) to check whether this is a *working tree*.  This allows you to distinguish between the "working tree" and "bare repository" cases:

```
$ git -C .git rev-parse && echo $?
0
$ git -C .git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree && echo $?
false
0
```

As always, be aware that if you're not in a Git directory at all, you get an error:

```
$  git -C / rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

which you may wish to discard (`git ... 2>/dev/null`).  Since `--is-inside-work-tree` prints `true` or `false` you'll want to capture or test stdout.

Answer (score 0):

In unix/linux systems, you can run `git status` and check the exit code `echo $?`.  Anything other than 0 would tell you aren't in a git repo