# Git Bash Slow on Windows 10

Tags: git, bash, windows-10

Anyone else having troubles with the Git Bash shell on Windows 10?  It's running extremely slow on my machine, which otherwise performs well.  The Git Bash shell was installed with Git for Windows and has not been modified.

Comment: Try this, worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24045966/675189

Comment: Thanks @rascob, I tried the config commands listed, but my git bash still takes over 20 seconds of blinking cursor before I see the command prompt...

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? 32-bit or 64-bit git/bash?

Comment: Both git/bash and Windows are 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

#### Did you try an alternative terminal emulator?

Like cmder: http://cmder.net

#### Or an alternative Shell?

Babun: http://babun.github.io/faq.html

- both have git preinstalled and preconfigured. Additionally Unix tools.

Comment: After fighting with the performance issue for a while, I started using bash for Windows (Windows subsystem for Linux) which performs nicely.  I would like to resolve the performance issues in the Git for Windows shell though, as it's the default shell for many other tools, i.e., SourceTree.