# Is it possible to have a global git config for different sites?

Tags: git, authentication, configuration

Imagine you have this git project folder structure:

- /home/user/gitlab
- /home/user/github

Is it possible to define somewhere in one place that git auth logic using certificates should be configured for all projects under one of the path correspondingly? And maybe also different user signatures?

Comment: See "Includes" in `git help config`.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/42675999/5784831

Comment: Are you accessing github and gitlab through ssh using ssh keys ? do you want to use `key1` when accessing gitlab, and `key2` when accessing github ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For access : you can use your `~/.ssh/config` file to set different keys for different servers.

```
# in your ~/.ssh/config file :

Host github.com
    IdentityFile path/to/github_key

Host gitlab.com
    IdentityFile path/to/gitlab_key
```

Once set up, any ssh interaction with `github.com` (resp. `gitlab.com`) -- e.g : `git clone git@github.com:repo`, `git fetch`, `git push` ... -- will use `github_key` (resp. `gitlab_key`) by default.

---

For `git` config parameters (e.g : `user.name` and `user.email`), you can use `includeIf` sections ([link to docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes)) as suggested by @choroba :

```
# in your .gitconfig file :
[includeIf "gitdir:~/github/**"]
    path = ~/path/to/github_conf_file

[includeIf "gitdir:~/gitlab/**"]
    path = ~/path/to/gitlab_conf_file
```

and set the `user.name` and `user.email` values in `github_conf_file` and `gitlab_conf_file`.

Comment: if I observe that e.g. git push keeps switching to user/password prompt, are there any error messages to check for?

Comment: UPD debugging settings found ```GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull``` but not helpful. Re-cloning the repo with git@.. was the trick. Thanks! is there a way not to re-clone?

Comment: On an existing repo : check the url defined for each remote matches