# Git action are super slow on a network shared

Tags: git

at my new job they work with the environment mounted on a shared so that the sys easily update dependencies for us dev. Leaving aside opinion on the approach I've got this situation where I've got my "local repo" mounted on my computer, but every single action take between 30 and 40 second, even for a simple git status. In my opinion it isn't a network speed related issue because at the office we've got 400MB up and down and the result is the same as at home where I have a mere 7.
This result is identical both on macOS Big Sur and Windows 10.

Has anyone ever worked with a similar approach and got the same issue?

**EDIT:** I've tried to clone the repo locally to see if there was any improvement and on my Mac it gets lighting fast, so I'm guessing it could be related to how the shared is set up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Bash is extremely slow on Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-on-windows-7-x64)

Comment: a. would it be okay in your situation to treat that shared drive as a remote, and clone it to some place on your local machine ?

Comment: b. is that "repo on a shared drive" a repo dedicated to your own usage ? or is it also actively used by other devs ?

Comment: @LeGEC it's a vhost dedicated to my usage

Comment: @dejdej nope, I've tried the cleanup and the optimization but still take around 30 sec to perform an action