# Outputting dirty state of git repo in command line issue

Tags: bash

if i run this in command line with in git repo

```
git status 2> /dev/null | grep -iw 'modified'
```

the output i get

```
#   modified:   .rvmrc
```

so my assumption is that if i plug this in into if statement i will get true that will execute the line of code

but when i created function as part of the .bash_profile, and here is the code i have:

```
## Prompt ##
path="$white\w$reset"
folder_name="$white\W$reset"
git_branch="\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e '\* ' | sed 's/^..\(.*\)/$red(\1)$reset/')"
rvm="$green(\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt i v p))$reset"

# Checks if working tree is dirty
function _git_st {
  if [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | grep -iw 'modified')  ]]; then
    echo "[x]"
  fi
}
git_st="$yellow`_git_st`$reset"

PS1="$rvm $folder_name $git_branch $git_st \$ "
```

X is not echoed.... i am bit lost, and not sure what i am doing wrong.

this is the out put i get:

```
(ruby-1.9.2-p290) folder-git (master)  $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .rvmrc
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(ruby-1.9.2-p290) folder-git (master)  $
```

Comment: As an aside, your `_git_st` function is a little more complicated than it needs to be. `if git status 2> /dev/null | grep -qiw 'modified'; then` should work the same, without needing to capture the output and check if it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are using a variable `git_st` to set `PS1` which will be evaluated at the time of setting `PS1`. What you can try is to invoke the function `_git_st` be called instead of using `git_st` i.e. try something on the lines of:
`PS1="$rvm $folder_name $git_branch \$(_git_st) \$ "`.
Also you might be interested to know that newer versions of `git` provide functions along with bash completion which provide such utilities. You can take a look at `__git_ps1` function if it is available.
Hope this helps!
P.S.: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133904/ps1-line-with-git-current-branch-and-colors) is SO post which might provide some pointers for using `__git_ps1`. [This](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Git_quick_reference) is the quick search result from Google.

Comment: Thank you @another.anon.coward for point out my flaw, will try this in a bit.

Comment: Thats it, its working. Thank you so much. I will check out links in a bit.