# git-bash: show email in Git Bash command prompt variable

Tags: git-bash

The command prompt in Git Bash displays the current branch name (with other information such as directory name, etc) as given below.

```
mylogin@SYSNAME MINGW64 ~/path/to/my/repo (master)
$
```

How can I include the repo user profile email along with the branch name?  The email is the user.email of the repo; which can be found using the command `git config user.email`.

I would like to have this value `git config user.email` in my command prompt along with the branch name as given below.

```
mylogin@SYSNAME MINGW64 ~/path/to/my/repo (master|myemail@github.com)
$
```

Please note I have a windows system.

Comment: Apply the result of `git config user.email` to your `PS1` environment variable to obtain the email and `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | tr -d '\n'` to obtain the current branch.

Comment: This one might be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133904/ps1-line-with-git-current-branch-and-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... The MinGW approach slightly differs from a "usual" bash approach because it has a very rich script to generate the `PS1` Bash variable. You just have to to the following (assuming you're using 64-bit too):

- find `/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh` or (%YOUR_GIT_LOCATION%`\mingw64\share\git\completion\git-prompt.sh`);
- modify the `gitstring` environment variable:
  replace `local gitstring="$c$b${f:+$z$f}$r$p"`
  with `local gitstring="$c$b${f:+$z$f}$r$p|$(git config user.email)"`.

---

The diff between my original version and my version with the `user.email` setting:

```
diff --git a/git-prompt.sh.BAK b/git-prompt.sh
index 07b52be..2d63680 100644
--- a/git-prompt.sh.BAK
+++ b/git-prompt.sh
@@ -515,7 +515,7 @@ __git_ps1 ()
        fi

        local f="$w$i$s$u"
-       local gitstring="$c$b${f:+$z$f}$r$p"
+       local gitstring="$c$b${f:+$z$f}$r$p|$(git config user.email)"

        if [ $pcmode = yes ]; then
                if [ "${__git_printf_supports_v-}" != yes ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks Lyubomyr.  It worked.  I could see both branch and email in my git bash command prompt.