# git bash on windows (mingw64) editing .bash_profile ps1

Tags: git, bash, mingw-w64, ps1

I am following the Udacity course where in Lesson 1 video 29. they talk about customizing the git bash and setting up workspace.

I did dig into how the .bash_profile should be edited and it almost works as I want it. Except I can't figure out how to add a new line in front of the command prompt $ sign.

```
TITLESTRING="Bash Prompt (Git for Windows) =>"
TITLE="\[\033]0;$TITLESTRING${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]"
export PS1="$TITLE\n$GREEN\u@\h$MAGENTA\$(__git_ps1) $LIGHT_YELLOW\w $RESET\n$ "
```

When I put the \n before the last $ sign in order to make it appear in the next line, then I get this error message on starting git bash:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1)'

Mik@BIG_PC~
$
```

When I don't have that \n in front of the last $ sign then all is good.

Please help me whit this.

Comment: `\\n` .. just guessing.

Comment: I have already tried that. In many possible combination.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working if you are using `$(__git_ps1)`, not `\$(__git_ps1)`.

I get:

```
vonc@bvonc (master) ~/data/git/git
$ git version
git version 2.12.1.windows.1
```

You can see many other examples of $(__git_ps1) usage in "[PS1 line with git current branch and colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4133904/6309)", and I never see `\$(...)`.