# Git pushd & popd? I.e., checkout last state

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm writing a Bash script, and I want to checkout a tag and then checkout back to where I started.

I tried `git co HEAD@{1}`, but when starting at master, that takes me back to the commit SHA of master but with a detatched head.

Is there something like `pushd` & `popd` for Git?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`git checkout @{-1}` which can be abbreviated to `git checkout -`.

[From the manpage:](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> As a special case, the "@{-N}" syntax
>   for the N-th last branch checks out
>   the branch (instead of detaching). You
>   may also specify - which is synonymous
>   with "@{-1}".

Comment: This is awesome! +1 for that simple way.

Comment: In which version of git can you do `git checkout -1`?  It doesn't work in git 1.7.1 and the man page says that `git checkout -` is equivalent to `git checkout @{-1}`

Comment: @Mark Longair: None.  I misremembered.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Of course! How intuitive. :) I should've tried that. That's just like `cd -`.

Comment: This is not the same. E.g. if you run git pull, `git checkout -` will take you back where you were before checking out the current (pulled) branch.

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT:* wnoise's suggestion will work if you don't want to keep an explicit history the way pushd/popd does.  If you do (and don't want an ordinary `checkout` to affect your LRU):

I don't know of anything that will do what you want out of the box, but it's not to hard to hack together something along those lines.  If you add a file named `git-foo` to your PATH, you get a new `git foo` command.  So, `git-pushd` could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=1
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed s_refs/heads/__ >> $GIT_DIR/.pushd
git checkout "$@"
```

And `git-popd`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=1
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

REF=$(head -n1 $GIT_DIR/.pushd)

[ -n "$REF" ] || die "No refs to pop"
git checkout "$REF" && sed -i -e '1d' $GIT_DIR/.pushd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with aliases and **/tmp/gitStack** as a temporary file to track your stack.

Checkout the main aliases I've made:

```
[alias]
  pushd         = "!f() { _BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref head); _BRANCH=${_BRANCH#'refs/heads/'}; echo $_BRANCH >> /tmp/gitStack; git checkout $@;}; f "
  pop           = "!f() { _BRANCH=$(tail -1 /tmp/gitStack); git checkout ${_BRANCH%*:}; head -n+1 /tmp/gitStack > /tmp/_gitStack; mv /tmp/_gitStack /tmp/gitStack; }; f"
  pop-clear     = "!f() { rm /tmp/gitStack; }; f"
  pop-list      = "!f() { cat /tmp/gitStack 2> /dev/null; }; f"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, first save the current branch (like written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch/1593487#1593487)):

```
branch_name="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)" ||
branch_name="(unnamed branch)"     # detached HEAD
branch_name=${branch_name##refs/heads/}
```

then go and checkout the tag you want to

```
git checkout -b tag_branch tag_name
```

Do what you want to do on that branch, then checkout the old branch again:

```
git checkout $branch_name
```

That's it.