# Customize CSH prompt for Git repo

Tags: git, prompt, csh

I want to have a custom CSH prompt when I am inside a Git repo. 
I want the prompt to look like this if I am not in a git repo

```
host_name>$
```

But when I am inside a Git repo must turn into something like this

```
host_name [GIT REPO ROOT DIR]>$
```

I just want to display the root of the Git repo (GIT REPO ROOT DIR), so that I know in which repo I am currently in. Instead of using 'pwd' everytime.

Do you guys have any suggesstions on achieveing this? Thanks for the help

-Anish

Comment: csh (depending on the version) doesn't provide any direct way to customize the prompt.  You could define aliases for the `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd` commands that update `$prompt`.  What OS are you on?  On many systems, `/bin/csh` is really a symlink to `/bin/tcsh`.  Are the variables `$tcsh` and `$version` set?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it for tcsh.  Put this script in your path someplace; call it cgb:

```
#!/bin/bash
git branch 2> /dev/null | grep '^*' | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

In your .tcshrc,

```
alias precmd 'set cgb=`cgb`'
set prompt='...your-prompt-string... (%$cgb) % '
```

precmd runs before every prompt.  If you only want it to run before changing directories, use alias cwdcmd instead.  I prefer precmd, since it'll run when doing a git checkout, for example.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch, I shouldn't be using "git branch" in scripts, since it's a porcelain command.  Substitute:  "git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null" for "git branch ..." above.

Answer (score 2):

I am still a diehard tcsh user, but I finally gave up on raw csh and switched to tcsh for many reasons, including csh's terrible support for things like this.  (And I may eventually give in and switch to bash, even. :-) )  Still, it's possible to do, as @KeithThompson noted, via aliases:

```
alias cd 'chdir \!:* && update_prompt'
alias update_prompt 'set prompt="...stuff here... "'
```

where "...stuff here..." can include using backquotes to run something, such as a script to generate the `[GIT REPO ROOT DIR]` part.  (Write the script in something other than csh!)

Note, while I aliased `cd` to `chdir ...` you can just use the command itself in the alias, which you will need with `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: Thanks @Keith Thompson and @torek. I was earlier doing this only and it works the way I want it to. I wanted to know if there was any other way of doing it. But the sad part is `git` command can get slow for a really large repo. I am thinking of finding my repo name w/o using the `git` cmd. I am planning to write a script to parse my `pwd` and get repo name as I have a specific dir structure.