# How can I change my tcsh prompt to show my current working directory?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I am using `tcsh`and I am  looking for a way responsive working directory where I at least want to display the last folder name instead of getting full path.

Imagine my current working directory is :

```
  [user@hostname/home/us/Desktop/my/projects]
```

then I would like to display the prompt like this :

```
    [user@hostname projects]
```

present I am using the `.cshrc` file in file I have written like this:

```
  alias setprompt 'set prompt="[suman@`hostname` `pwd`:~] $"'
  alias setprompt 'set prompt="${LightGreen}[${yellow}suman${Light}${LightPurple}@%m ${LightGreen}:~] ${yellow}$ ${end} "'
```

I don't have PS1 variable also and don't know what it does, and I would like to know the difference between `.cshrc` file and `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I find that when I'm working in directories that are many levels deep and the names are long, the prompt on the RHS of the screen is not helpful.  Personally, I decline to put the working directory in my prompt.  But by all means go and find the other questions on the topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: custom PS1 with nice working directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/bash-custom-ps1-with-nice-working-directory-path)

Comment: The `.cshrc` file is used by the C shell; the `.bashrc` file is used by Bash.  You can look at, amongst many other questions, [Bash: custom PS1 with nice working directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/bash-custom-ps1-with-nice-working-directory-path).

Comment: Perhaps it goes without saying... but if you want to see what your `prompt` is currently set to before you go changing it, you can just do `echo $prompt`

Answer (score 36):

You can use:

```
set prompt = '[%n@%m %c]$ '
```

`%n` for the username, `%m` for the hostname up to the first `.`, and `%c` for the last directory part. There are a large number of such substitutions available, you can find a list of them in `tcsh(1)`, duplicated below for convenience.

Using `` `pwd` `` won't work, because the `cshrc` file is read only *once* on shelll startup, not on every directory change.

> I would like to know the difference between .cshrc file and .bashrc file.

The `cshrc` file is used by `csh` and `tcsh`, the `bashrc` file is used by `bash`. Although they serve the same purpose, they're different programs (like `~/.mozilla/firefox` and `~/.config/chromium`).

---

```
%/  The current working directory.
%~  The current working directory, but with one's  home  direc‐
    tory  represented  by `~' and other users' home directories
    represented  by  `~user'  as  per  Filename   substitution.
    `~user'  substitution happens only if the shell has already
    used `~user' in a pathname in the current session.
%c[[0]n], %.[[0]n]
    The trailing component of the current working directory, or
    n  trailing  components if a digit n is given.  If n begins
    with `0', the number  of  skipped  components  precede  the
    trailing  component(s)  in the format `/<skipped>trailing'.
    If the ellipsis shell variable is set,  skipped  components
    are  represented  by  an  ellipsis  so  the  whole  becomes
    `...trailing'.  `~' substitution is done as in `%~'  above,
    but  the  `~'  component  is ignored when counting trailing
    components.
%C  Like %c, but without `~' substitution.
%h, %!, !
    The current history event number.
%M  The full hostname.
%m  The hostname up to the first `.'.
%S (%s)
    Start (stop) standout mode.
%B (%b)
    Start (stop) boldfacing mode.
%U (%u)
    Start (stop) underline mode.
%t, %@
    The time of day in 12-hour AM/PM format.
%T  Like `%t', but in 24-hour format (but see  the  ampm  shell
    variable).
%p  The  `precise'  time  of  day in 12-hour AM/PM format, with
    seconds.
%P  Like `%p', but in 24-hour format (but see  the  ampm  shell
    variable).
\c  c is parsed as in bindkey.
^c  c is parsed as in bindkey.
%%  A single `%'.
%n  The user name.
%N  The effective user name.
%j  The number of jobs.
%d  The weekday in `Day' format.
%D  The day in `dd' format.
%w  The month in `Mon' format.
%W  The month in `mm' format.
%y  The year in `yy' format.
%Y  The year in `yyyy' format.
%l  The shell's tty.
%L  Clears  from the end of the prompt to end of the display or
    the end of the line.
%$  Expands the shell or environment variable name  immediately
    after the `$'.
%#  `>'  (or the first character of the promptchars shell vari‐
    able) for normal users, `#' (or  the  second  character  of
    promptchars) for the superuser.
%{string%}
    Includes string as a literal escape sequence.  It should be
    used only to change terminal attributes and should not move
    the  cursor  location.  This cannot be the last sequence in
    prompt.
%?  The return code of the command  executed  just  before  the
    prompt.
%R  In prompt2, the status of the parser.  In prompt3, the cor‐
    rected string.  In history, the history string.

`%B', `%S', `%U' and `%{string%}' are available in only  eight-
bit-clean shells; see the version shell variable.

The  bold,  standout  and underline sequences are often used to
distinguish a superuser shell.  For example,

    > set prompt = "%m [%h] %B[%@]%b [%/] you rang? "
    tut [37] [2:54pm] [/usr/accts/sys] you rang? _

If `%t', `%@', `%T', `%p', or `%P' is used, and noding  is  not
set,  then print `DING!' on the change of hour (i.e, `:00' min‐
utes) instead of the actual time.

Set by default to `%# ' in interactive shells.
```

Comment: True, `pwd` won't work in `set prompt` in a `.chsrc`, but `precmd` can be used to set the prompt each time before the prompt is printed.  (eg, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973266/customize-csh-prompt-for-git-repo/13090820#13090820)

Comment: @Martin, Can you please mention the source of this list and a good reference/user-guide for `csh`?

Comment: All of this is from `man csh` @KhaledIsmail

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Randall, set the `precmd` alias:

```
alias precmd 'set prompt = "`echo $cwd` %# "'
```

Make the change permanent:

```
cat >> .cshrc << 'EOF'

# Custom prompt
alias precmd 'set prompt = "`echo $cwd` %# "'
'EOF'
```

Comment: Echoing the cwd variable is faster than issuing pwd; don't use pwd.

Answer (score -1):

> Edit: I had assumed that the question would be about bash, because it
>   was tagged like that.

`.cshrc` is the configuration file for csh or tcsh, wheras `.bashrc` is the configuration file for, well, bash. Even if they serve a similar purpose, bash and csh are simply different programs, so the configuration for one will not necessarily work for the other.

So what you need to do is to put a line like this into your .bashrc

```
PS1='...\w$ '
```

where `\w` is the magic code which will be expanded to the current working directory, as you can look up in the bash's man page in section "Prompting".

A more complete example, taken from the default setting of Cygwin's bash package, can look like this:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

It will be expanded to a prompt like this (but with colors, uuuh):

```
user@machine currentdir $
```

Comment: And `\W` corresponds to the last step in CWD.

Comment: sorry to say this  i have only .cshrc file, and i cretaed one .bashrc file and i did what you said even though when i source the .bashrc file it is giving the following error  PS1: Command not found

Comment: But you are sure you're running bash, not csh or the like? If in doubt, run `ps -p $$` and check whether the Command column actually refers to bash.

Comment: Not bash i am running in tcsh