# Alias for cd in Linux csh

Tags: linux, terminal, alias, csh

I used to have an alias for `cd` in csh, which can show the current time and directory at the beginning of the cmdline and trigger the `ls` command.
The effect is like this:

```
[10:24] /home/cambridgelv/Desktop/cd ..
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music
[10:24] /home/cambridgelv/cd Desktop
abc.doc  def.jpg
[10:25] /home/cambridgelv/Desktop/
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: An idea for what?

Comment: @carlfriedrich to implement these function, for example, to trigger ls, is should be "alias cd 'cd ; ls'", but how to implement the other two function, I don't know.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter

Comment: @carlfriedrich These 3 effects could be implemented through one-line alias command, I used it for years, but I lost this command just a few days ago.

Comment: @Dominique Not exactly. I will try to recollect this alias if possible. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That's for bash @Dominique, not csh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer it by myself.
I thought maybe I aliased the `set prompt` command into cd before, so we can do this separately.
Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037878/11768989
You can customize the prompt in any way.
Mine is look like this:

```
set prompt = '%{\e[35;40;1m%}[%T @%m]%{\e[0m%} %~/'
alias cd "cd \!:1; ls"
```

Comment: I mean that the one-line command maybe is ```alias cd "set prompt = '%{\e[35;40;1m%}[%T @%m]%{\e[0m%} %~/';cd \!:1; ls"```, which is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to hook in to the special `cwdcmd` alias; this gets run every time the current directory changes.

```
alias cwdcmd 'printf "[%s] " `date +%H:%m`'
```

For example, where `>` is the prompt:

```
> sleep 1

> cd /
[14:06] > sleep 1
> cd ~
[14:06] >
```

---

You can also alias `cd` with something like:

```
alias cd 'cd $* && printf "[%s] " `date +%H:%m`'
```

Where `$*` expand to the command arguments `/dir` in `cd /dir`. However, this also prints the directory in square brackets for some reason that I don't quite understand. The `cwdcmd` alias is better anyway.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a full answer, since it doesn't do the `ls`; I forgot about that. Getting the `ls` in there is a bit more effort as you want the date *before* the prompt and the `ls` *after* the prompt.