# Jenkins: Find out which Branch got pushed to GitHub?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, jenkins

Is there an easy way to find out which branch triggered a build process in Jenkins?
I am using the [Jenkins GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+plugin) and GitHub Webhooks.

Instead of setting up a CI Job for each Branch I want to create a central script that will handle this automatically.

Any Ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a look into the source and it looks like the GitHub plugin uses the Git plugin under the hood: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin

if that's the case, you should be able to use the env-var `GIT_BRANCH`

Comment: I just tried this recently and it's not working as expected. I'm also using the Jenkins Github plugin version 1.19.2 and `GIT_BRANCH` is `null` both when the build is triggered by pushing and when it's triggered by merging a pull request. Any pointers?

Comment: GIT_BRANCH and GIT_COMMIT should be set. look into the current documentation https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Answer (score -1):

I'm using version [1.19.2 of the Github Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin) and relying on the `GIT_BRANCH` didn't work. This and the other variables specified in the Git plugin's documentation are all `null` in my case. Don't know why.

So, after researching these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch) I decided to use [the `git-name-rev` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev). This is how I did it:

```
def cmd = 'git name-rev --name-only HEAD > branch'
isUnix()?sh(cmd):bat(cmd)
def branch = readFile('branch').trim()
echo("Branch is '${branch}'")
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: if you have a comment, please use the comment functionality.

Comment: Hi @phoet , this is not a comment. Look again. It's an answer. Since this is a misunderstanding, I would appreciate it if you could remove the down-vote.

Comment: don't know what happened here... unfortunately i can't revoke my vote unless the answer has been edited.