# Write Git info strings to exe file C#

Tags: c#, git, logging, msbuild, mono

I need to write git information: *Commit name, tags, branch, etc* 
to a binary (exe) file.

It is needed to run strings * | grep git, on that file to simply view latest git info about it.
I know that AssemblyInfo is displayed when I run this command (without grep), but I'm facing two possible problems:

1. I'm not sure if I can write to AssemblyInfo from code, to run 'git log' command and then get its output and write into AssemblyInfo.
2. If I want to use command 'git log' then it's not going to work on Windows, but it is possible that my App will be built on Windows and not on unix environment.

Maybe you know another way to do that?

Comment: when do you want this to happen - on build or submit?

Comment: i want it to happen on build

Comment: I found that AssemblyInfo is written to the end of exe file in 'string' format so the 'strings *' command show me what in there. It's the perfect way for to simply add to this AssemblyInfo 'git log' output, but I can't run 'git log' on Windows machine.

Comment: what is your build environment - msbuild?

Comment: Actually, mono and msbuild, and I need it to work on both.

Comment: do you have a CI build server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25696/discussion-between-user1243496-and-daniel-a-white)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done in your build script, filling a templated version of your AssemblyInfo (look at mustache, a templating language).

This build step does the following:

- get the necessary info with git plumbing commands (e.g. [How to programmatically determine the current checked out Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch))
- generate the AssemblyInfo file using a template.

Then your software build continues as usual.

Comment: Well, I didn't actually understood what you mean 'look at mustache'. But I'm facing problem when I try to build my app on windows machine, because I can't run 'git' commands since they're not built in cmd.

Comment: @user1243496: Just add the path to git.exe to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: that sounds nice, but I need more universal way, for example If I want to build it on machine where no git.exe in PATH environment variable. Another way is to read files in .git folder, but I find it impractical..

Comment: IMHO you're adding too much constraints by wanting to build on a machine without git in PATH. It is possible, but why? this info is very difficult to get without git, and git is installable in a matter of minutes. If you insist you can include a portable git along with your code, but I find it akward.

Comment: Thanks for you opinion, I really appreciate it. Well, I'll re-consider that part. Will try in few moments your answer, It seems to be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .net wrapper for Git windows implementation. Some high profile [projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx) use this implementation.  https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp, http://libgit2.github.com/