# git plumbing to tell the checked out branch

Tags: git

Scripting git, I need to find out the checked-out branch name.  So far it seems the only "reliable" way to do that is with `git branch | sed -n '/^\* /s///p'`.  (Scare quotes because of things like `color.branch` or `column.branch` in .gitconfig; it's not reliable at all.)  The only other thing I found is `git name-rev`, but that seems to return the first (sorted by names) branch that points to HEAD:

```
> git checkout master
> git checkout -b another
> git checkout master
> git name-rev HEAD
HEAD another
```

Is there something better than `sed -n '\#^ref: refs/heads/#s###p' .git/HEAD` to figure out the checked out branch?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a little `git` invocation I've used in a couple of scripts, that either gives back `refs/heads/branchname`, or if you're not on a branch, it gives the SHA of your detached HEAD:

```
cur_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>> /dev/null || git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Removing the `refs/heads/` prefix should be pretty simple, if you need it...

Comment: `--short` takes care of the prefix and `-q` suppresses output on stderr.

Comment: `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` for the lazy :)

Answer (score 9):

Just output the branch you are on with:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

There should be no trouble also if you have more than one branches, and if you aren't on any branch it just gives you `HEAD`

Comment: Both this and twalberg's answers are correct for the question as stated and I've upvoted both of them.  If it was possible to accept multiple answers, I would do it in this case.  `git symbolic-ref` won because I prefer non-zero exit code for detached HEAD.  Unstated requirements, I know.