# How do I get just the branch from a Git command?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, qmake, buildbot, monotone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show just the current branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git)

I am moving my monotone DVCS to git.  In my build setup I have qmake get the current revision and the current branch (because these are build on buildbot) so that it can be used as a define.

```
exists(_MTN):DEFINES += BUILDREVISION=\\\"$$system(mtn automate get_base_revision_id)\\\"
else:DEFINES += BUILDREVISION=\\\"NOT \
    BUILT \
    FROM \
    SOURCE \
    REPOSITORY\\\"

# Check which branch we are building
exists(_MTN):DEFINES += BUILDBRANCH=\\\"$$system(mtn au get_option branch)\\\"
else:DEFINES += BUILDBRANCH=\\\"UNKNOWN\\\"
```

In git I can do:

```
exists(.git):DEFINES += BUILDREVISION=\\\"$$system(git rev-parse HEAD)\\\"
else:DEFINES += BUILDREVISION=\\\"NOT \
    BUILT \
    FROM \
    SOURCE \
    REPOSITORY\\\"

# Check which branch we are building
exists(.git):DEFINES += BUILDBRANCH=\\\"$$system(git show-branch --current)\\\"
else:DEFINES += BUILDBRANCH=\\\"UNKNOWN\\\"
```

My problems are that "git show-branch --current" has the commit message with it and a new line character in it, which my compiler doesn't like.  How can I get git to be more succinct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
master
```

If you're not on any branch (i.e. you've detached HEAD) then this will just return `HEAD`, but it sounds as if in your use case you're always expecting to be on a branch.

*Update: In fact it's even simpler, you can just do:* `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

No git command give you only the current branch, so you have to modify its output to extract it:

```
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | grep "*" | sed s/*\ //
1                                    2          3
```

Explanation:

1. get branch list
2. select current branch, prefixed with `*`
3. remove the `*`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat .git/HEAD | sed 's/.*\///'
```

The `sed 's/.*\///'` part removes the "ref: refs/heads/" from the beginning of the line.